# How to save "history" automatically depending on the directory

Tags: c, bash, scripting, shell, history

I work extensively using the shell. When I continue working on some project one week later, I go to some "folder" and realize that I do not remember what I was doing. Sometimes and before stopping work what I do is:

```
history  > DIRX_HISTORY_20100922
```

so later I have a look at the commands I used, I can remember much better what I was doing.

I wonder if somehow, some script or something could do this automatically each time I type a command in a directory, so this DIRX_HISTORY_20100922 is created and a new one is modified depending on the date and on the directory name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my [history logging functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945288/saving-current-directory-to-bash-history). They save the current directory along with the command that was executed. You can `grep` for the directory and it will show you the commands that you were using there.

Answer (score 0):

Bash's PROMPT_COMMAND variable can be used to save the last line of your history to a file for every command you enter.

ie.

PROMPT_COMMAND="history 1 >> DIRX_HISTORY"

Comment: where do you store this, on the .bashrc?