# Is there any way to get bash command history before the ones in ./bash_history?

Tags: bash, history

I want to get my bash command history as many as possible, I find ./bash_history only contains most recent two thousands lines, does it mean the ones before that is lost forever? Is there anyway to get it back.

Thanks a lot.
Roy987

Comment: That value depends on the value set in `HISTFILESIZE` along with values of other environment variables (i.e. HISTSIZE, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid your past history is lost forever.  But you can preserve it in the future.  Increasing `$HISTSIZE` and `$HISTFILESIZE` helps, but if you really want to keep all your commands forever, check out [this tip](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/543).

Comment: +1 Very nice tip! See also my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945288/saving-current-directory-to-bash-history) for ways to save even more detail.