# Compound 'if' statements with multiple expressions in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I would like to recreate something like this

```
if ( arg1 || arg2 || arg 3) {}
```

And I did got so far, but I get the following error:

```
line 11: [.: command not found

if [ $char == $';' -o $char == $'\\' -o $char == $'\'' ]
then ...
```

I tried different ways, but none seemed to work. [Some of the ones I tried](http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/programming/multiple-expression-if-statement-in-bash.html).

Comment: There's probably not any need to use `$''`.

Comment: Using `==` inside of `[ ]` isn't actually valid POSIX sh, even though bash allows it. Use only a single `=` for string comparison tests.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Bash, you can use the `[[ ]]` form rather than `[ ]`, which allows `&&` and `||` internally:

```
if [[ foo || bar || baz ]] ; then
  ...
fi
```

Otherwise, you can use the usual Boolean logic operators externally:

```
[ foo ] || [ bar ] || [ baz ]
```

...or use operators specific to the `test` command ([though modern versions of the POSIX specification describe this XSI extension as deprecated -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/test.html)):

```
[ foo -o bar -o baz ]
```

...which is a differently written form of the following, which is similarly deprecated:

```
test foo -o bar -o baz
```

Comment: I would have sworn I tried this before without result.. probably did something different, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Bash's `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` are more powerful and flexible than `[ ]`.

- `[[ ]]` is for strings and `(( ))` is for integer logic and arithmetic
- `&&` and `||` operators can be used inside `[[ ]]` and `(( ))`, and `()` can be used for grouping
- No need to quote variable expansions inside `[[ ]]` or `(( ))` - Bash doesn't do [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) or globbing in these contexts
- Inside `(( ))`, there is no need for a `$` behind variable names to expand them
- `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` can span multiple lines, without the need for a line continuation with `\`

Using these, we can write clean, readable, and more reliable code.

## Examples

### Compound statements with integers

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
((a == 2 || (b == 2 && c == 3))) && echo yes                   # yields yes
```

### Compound statements with strings

```
x=apple y=mango z=pear
[[ $x == orange || ($y == mango && $z == pear) ]] && echo yes  # yields yes
```

## [ equivalents for the above statements, using {}

```
[ "$a" -eq 2 ] || { [ "$b" -eq 2 ] && [ "$c" -eq 3 ]; }
[ "$x" == orange ] || { [ $y == mango ] && [ "$z" == pear ]; }
```

---

## Related

- [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188199/6862601)
- [Comparing integers: arithmetic expression or conditional expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278707/201820) on Unix & Linux
- [Test for non-zero length string in Bash: [ -n “$var” ] or [ “$var” ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825114/6862601)
- [Conditional Expressions - Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 4):

[Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267582/418413) is correct in that it shows you how to do logical operations on commands within (and without, for that matter) an `if` statement, but it looks more like you want to use `case` here:

```
case $char in
    \;|\\|\') echo found;;
    *) echo 'not found';;
esac
```

Comment: Good call -- admittedly, I looked a bit much at the literal question as opposed to intent.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, to group conditionals using the `[ ]` construct you must surround each group using parenthesis.  Each opening/closing parenthesis must be escaped and preceded/succeeded with a white space.  See below:

```
if [ \( "$char" = "$;" \) -o \( "$char" = "$\\" \) -o \( "$char" = "$\" \) ]
```

As such, it's definitely best to follow everyone elses advice and use bash's newer `[[ ]]` construct.  Lastly, as I understand it `==` is a relational operator intended to be used with-in arithmetic expressions. i.e. -

```
$((3==4))
```

Cameron Newham and Bill Rosenblatt, "Learning the bash Shell" Jan.1998