# Groups of compound conditions in Bash test

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to have some groups of conditions in a Bash *if* statement. Specifically, I'm looking for something like the following:

```
if <myCondition1 and myCondition2> or <myCondition3 and myCondition4> then...
```

How may I group the conditions together in the way I describe for use with one *if* statement in Bash?

Comment: I did but was unable to find the grouping trick (and didn't know the terminology to search in order to find it). When in doubt, ask. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'm not sure this should be marked as a duplicate. The answer to this question specifically addresses grouping conditions, whereas the answer to the duplicate does not.

Comment: I'm always amazed how easily questions can be marked as duplicates when they are clearly not. This question is about grouping conditions. There is nothing in the answers of that other question that actually answers this one.

Comment: Related: [Compound if statements with multiple expressions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11267569/6862601)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Use the && (and) and || (or) operators:

```
if [[ expression ]] && [[ expression ]] || [[ expression ]] ; then
```

They can also be used within a single [[ ]]:

```
if [[ expression && expression || expression ]] ; then
```

And, finally, you can group them to ensure order of evaluation:

```
if [[ expression && ( expression || expression ) ]] ; then
```

Comment: IMO this is a clearer answer than the "duplicate". In the third example, make sure to use double brackets - `[[ ]]`

Comment: For those who care about compatibility with other shell types, I'll note that doing the above does not appear to work with single brackets `[]`.

Comment: Be aware that in the first example, the `&&` and `||` are the shell's pipeline operators.  In the second and third examples, they are operators handled by the `[[...]]` conditional command parser.  The first works on exit values of zero and non-zero, the rest work on return values of true and false.  While all of the examples _work_, they work for different reasons.

Comment: this question answers me.  I wanted to know if it was possible to group using braces, then add  more conditions after the group.  This demonstrates that use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290146/multiple-logical-operators-a-b-c-and-syntax-error-near-unexpected-t .

Comment: and how can you break down a long line (e.g. more than 80 chars) of several conditions?  Line-continuation `\` and then newline after a logical operator where it makes sense to?

Comment: @tarabyte You can end the line with a backslash `\` and continue on the next line. It doesn't matter if the backslash comes before or after a logical operator.

Comment: The grouping example doesn't seem to work in bash 5:
/tmp/t: line 3: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `)'
/tmp/t: line 3: syntax error near `)'
/tmp/t: line 3: `if [[ (  1 -eq 0 && 1 -eq 1 ) || 1 -eq 1 ) ]] ; then'
But this does: if [[   1 -eq 0 && 1 -eq 1 ]] || [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] ; then