# Group various conditions inside one IF in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to group these conditions but it's returning:

```
awaited conditional binary operator
waiting for `)'
syntax error next to `$thetime'
`  ( dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '09:30:00' && dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '11:00:00' ) ||'
```

I already try like:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290146/multiple-logical-operators-a-b-c-and-syntax-error-near-unexpected-t

[Groups of compound conditions in Bash test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964805/groups-of-compound-conditions-in-bash-test)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

thetime=$(date +%H:%M:%S)

if [[
  ( dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '09:30:00' && dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '11:00:00' ) ||
  ( dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '13:00:00' && dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '17:00:00' )
]]; then
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j REJECT
else
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j ACCEPT
fi
```

Comment: `--gt` is not a `bash` operator; is it an option supported by whatever `dateutils.dtest` is?

Comment: yes, it is from dateutils.dtest params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

thetime=$(date +%H:%M:%S)

if ( $(dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '09:30:00') && $(dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '11:00:00') ) || ( $( dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '13:00:00' ) && $( dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '17:00:00' ) ); then
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j REJECT
else
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j ACCEPT
fi
```

Comment: @MarcoA.Braghim Are you expecting output from `dateutils.dtest`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `dateutils.dtest` is just an ordinary executable that uses its arguments to perform some sort of comparison, you want something like

```
if { dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '09:30:00' &&
     dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '11:00:00'; } ||
   { dateutils.dtest $thetime --gt '13:00:00' &&
     dateutils.dtest $thetime --lt '17:00:00'; }; then
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j REJECT
else
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j ACCEPT
fi
```

This assumes, for example, that `dateutils.dtest` has an exit status of 0 if `$thetime` is after 9:30:00, and a non-zero exit status otherwise.

The braces (`{ ... }`) act as grouping operators since `&&` and `||` have equal precedence in shell; note the semicolon before each closing `}` is required.

Comment: The other answer attempts to execute the output of `dateutils.dtest` as an additional command (unless they produce no output, in which case the command substitutions aren't necessary).

Answer (score -2):

I would lose the colons (:) and do the following comparison:

```
thetime=$(date +%H%M%S)

if [ "$thetime" -gt "093000" ] && [ "$thetime" -lt "110000" ] || [ "$thetime" -gt "130000" ] && [ "$thetime" -lt "170000" ]; then
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j REJECT
else
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.85.36 -j ACCEPT
fi
```