# bash IF condition with OR logic syntax

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, logical-operators, md5sum

i am confused..

i just make *if file does not exist OR md5 sum is wrong*

something like this

```
md5=20ffa23fbb589484d03d79608fe8d2ad
if ! -f /tmp/1.txt  || echo -n ${md5} /tmp/1.txt | md5sum --status --check -
then
 ....
fi
```

how write valid syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a logical OR operation in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111475/608639), [Simple logical operators in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270440/608639), [Groups of compound conditions in Bash test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965071/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww The second one is pretty close, but doesn't cover mixing conditional expressions with other types of commands (which is important in this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things in an `if` condition are commands (like `echo ... | md5sum ...`), not conditional expressions (like `-f /tmp/1.txt`). In order to use a conditional expression, you need to use the `test` command:

```
if ! test -f /tmp/1.txt  || echo -n ${md5} /tmp/1.txt | md5sum --status --check -
```

or its synonym `[` (note that it expects a "`]`" as its last argument, so it looks like funny parentheses):

```
if ! [ -f /tmp/1.txt ]  || echo -n ${md5} /tmp/1.txt | md5sum --status --check -
```

or in bash or zsh, you can use `[[ ]]` (which isn't a regular command, and has somewhat cleaner syntax for more complex conditions):

```
if ! [[ -f /tmp/1.txt ]]  || echo -n ${md5} /tmp/1.txt | md5sum --status --check -
```

BTW, I'm pretty sure you also want to negate the md5 status check, so you need another "`!`" to negate that as well:

```
if ! [[ -f /tmp/1.txt ]]  || ! echo -n ${md5} /tmp/1.txt | md5sum --status --check -
```

Edit: I'd also recommend skipping the `-n` option on `echo` -- it doesn't seem to be necessary, and it isn't portable. So some versions of `echo` will just print "-n" as part of their output, which will confuse `md5sum`. I had a bunch of scripts that used `echo -n`, and had to rewrite them in a panic after a system update changed the behavior of `echo`... so ever since then I've avoided it like the plague, and used `printf` when I need something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
md5hash=031f8c1dba9b8ca6890a7f3dc13428f2
[ ! -f /tmp/1.txt ] || md5arr=( $(md5sum /tmp/1.txt) ) && [ ${md5arr[0]} == $md5hash ]
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "no file or file changed"
```