# Bash script to monitor Mongo db doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, bash

I am writing a bash script to monitor my MongoDB status. once it is crash then restart it. the script is as below:

```
while true
do
    ret = $("mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf")
    if $ret == 0
    then
        echo "I am out with code 0."
        break
    fi
    echo "running again"
done
echo "I am out with code $?"
```

But it seems doesn't work. Return from the system:

```
running again
./mongo-text: line 3: mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf: No such file or directory
./mongo-text: line 3: ret: command not found
./mongo-text: line 4: ==: command not found
```

not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does the user running the script have access to /etc/mongod.conf?

Comment: yes, it works fine in linux command line.

Comment: I think there are a few problems with that bash script. `ret = $` shouldn't have spaces. `$ret == 0` likely wants `((` around it. shellcheck might be able to help find some of the issues

Comment: My knowledge on bash is feeble at best but I would think you would need another set of quotes to make `"mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf"`  into `"mongod --config '/etc/mongod.conf'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop can be made much simpler:

```
while ! mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf; do
    echo "running again" >&2
    sleep 1
done
if test -n "$VERBOSE"; then echo 'modgod successful'; fi
```

Note that the `if` keyword executes a command.  So `if $ret == 0` attempts to run the command `$ret` (assuming that variable is non-empty and contains no whitespace) with the arguments `==` and `0`.  That is almost certainly not what you intend.  It is more typical to write `if test "$ret" = 0` or `if [ "$ret" = 0 ]`.  If `$ret` is empty, then it is attempting to execute the command `==` with the single argument `0`.

Comment: one more question. When I tried to put it to the background with "nohup mongo-text &", it did bring up the mongod program, but itself died. how can I run it in the background?

Comment: If you want it to run in the background, you'll have a difficult time checking the return status.  Unless you `wait` for it, which seems to defeat the purpose of running it in the background.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code:

- `$("mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf")` will try to run `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` as a command, with spaces included
- the `if` syntax is wrong

You can rewrite it this way:

```
while :; do
    if mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf; then
        echo "I am out with code 0."
        break
    fi
    echo "running again"
    # probably sleep for a few seconds here
done
echo "I am out with code $?"
```

---

For info about `if` statements, see:

- [How to check the exit status using an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26675681/6862601)
- [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2237080/6862601)
- [Compound if statements with multiple expressions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55524251/6862601)