# Properly nesting conditionals in if statements

Tags: bash, if-statement, nested

I had a set of conditionals working perfectly. However, I needed to tweak the algorithm (making it more complicated), which involved nested conditionals in bash.

For instance, here is one such block:

```
a1=C
a2=P
a3=E
a4=1
a5=7
a6=0
a7=4
a8=T
a9=K
a10=S
letters=$(echo {A..Z} | tr -d ' ')
if [ "$c3" != "$a3" ]
    then
        c3=${letters:$((RANDOM%26+1)):1}
        if [ "$c3" == "$a3" ] && (( $count % $difficulty3 != 0 ))
        then
            c3=${letters:$((RANDOM%26+1)):1}
            if [ "$c3" == "$a3" ] && [ [ "$c1" != "$a1" ] || [ "$c2" != "$a2" ] ]
            then
                c3=${letters:$((RANDOM%26+1)):1}
            fi
        fi
    fi
```

The innermost if statement essentially checks, if `c3` and `a3` are equal, to make sure that `c1` and `a1` are also equal and that `c2` and `a2` are also equal. If not, it reassigns the variable `c3` once more.

My thought is to do an `if (true AND ( true OR true))` type logic, but this doesn't seem to work here. I get:

```
line 367: [: too many arguments
```

All the c and a variables are a single letter *or* numerical digit, so strings with spaces as I've seen in related SO posts on this subject are **not** causing the issue.

When I try doing double brackets instead of single around the whole thing, the script fails to run at all. Parentheses won't work since these aren't arithmetic operations... so I'm scratching my head now. It *seems* this is the proper way to do nested conditionals... what am I missing?

Comment: @Roadowl Basically what I am trying to do is if all the lowered number a and c variables are matching, it's fine, but if *not* (if any of them are NOT equal), then I do the assignment again

Comment: Can you add some initial values to the script so others can run it and see it fails in the way you describe?

Comment: @Roadowl That's it, the code runs on its own, except for 1 variable which I added - I see you also meant the comparison variables, I just added those

Comment: Consider using `[[`.  See this answer: [Compound if statements with multiple expressions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55524251/6862601).

Comment: @InterLinked : You never assign something to `difficulty3`.

Comment: @user1934428 I did, I forgot to add that code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets look like special shell syntax but they're not at all. `[` is just another name for `test`, and the closing `]` is merely an argument that's ignored.

You can use curly braces, which *are* special syntax:

```
if [ "$c3" == "$a3" ] && { [ "$c1" != "$a1" ] || [ "$c2" != "$a2" ]; }
```

Parentheses also work. The extra `;` isn't needed, but they create an unnecessary sub-shell, so I recommend curly braces:

```
if [ "$c3" == "$a3" ] && ( [ "$c1" != "$a1" ] || [ "$c2" != "$a2" ] )
```