# Error in while loop for checking the file existence only for a fixed time

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need to write a while loop to check for a file existence.

My requirement is: check for the file only for 5 minutes. If file come in that path within 5 minutes exit the loop and continue rest of the script otherwise exit from the script after 5 minutes with an error 'file not found'. I wrote the code like this :

```
SOURCEFILE=/path/*file.csv    
StartTime=$(date +'%s')    
TimeSpan=300
EndTime=$((StartTime + TimeSpan))

while [[ ! -f ${SOURCEFILE} && $(date +'%s') < ${EndTime} ]]    
do

  echo "inside loop"    
  sleep 25

done    
echo "outside loop"
```

But with this while loop, even if the file is present in the mentioned path, it is going inside loop and will exit only after 300 seconds. I am beginner in shell scripting and I am not able to understand the issue. I am using ksh.

I could also tell you that it works find with `while [ ! -f {SOURCEFILE} ]` only. But whenever I add any `&&` condition to while loop , then the `-f` is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `SOURCEFILE=/path/*file.csv` is wrong in your case. It can't be evaluated right with the `-f` flag.

An easy solution would be to use `find` or `ls` and count the result:

```
find /path/ -name "*file.csv" -type f
# then count the result...
```

Now I think there is a logic issue with the operators precedence. To force evaluation of the `!` for the `-f` only, use parenthesis. Here is what works for me, and you must adapt it a little to match the `*` before `file.csv`:

```
while [[  ( ! -f file.csv ) && $(date +'%s') < ${EndTime} ]]
do
  echo "inside loop"    
  sleep 25
...
```

There are some more explanation [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826462/6019417). The "and" operator precedes the "not", that's why you had the issue.

Comment: Hi Chomel , Thank You for the reply .But it didn't work .even if the fiel is not present in the location , RETCODE is getting value as 0 .I am not able to understand why ? Because of this it is not entering in to the loop.

Comment: in my previous code when i just used  while [ ! -f {SOURCEFILE} ] loop worked fine . but whenever i add any && condition to while loop , then the -f is not working properly

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't test the other case `:)

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is getting the asterisk (`*`) to expand at the 'right time'.

It doesn't help that the `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` constructs behave differently, especially when it comes to if/when to expand that asterisk. [You can peruse the [google search for 'ksh single bracket vs double bracket'](https://www.google.com/search?q=ksh+single+bracket+vs.+double+bracket&oq=ksh+single+bracket+vs+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i59.8354j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for more details.]

Try running the following to see the differences between single/double brackets and unquoted/single-quoted/double-quoted variable:

```
SOURCEFILE=/path/*file.csv
set -x
[ ! -f ${SOURCEFILE} ] && echo 'missing'
[ ! -f '${SOURCEFILE}' ] && echo 'missing'
[ ! -f "${SOURCEFILE}" ] && echo 'missing'
[[ ! -f ${SOURCEFILE} ]] && echo 'missing'
[[ ! -f '${SOURCEFILE}' ]] && echo 'missing'
[[ ! -f "${SOURCEFILE}" ]] && echo 'missing'
```

NOTE: Notice which tests expand the asterisk and which are looking for a (literal) asterisk in the name.

NOTE: Try adding a space to your file name (eg, `*file XX.csv`) and run the above tests ... tricky, tricky, tricky ...

For this particular case ... asterisk/wildcard in file name, no spaces, ksh ... you'll likely be ok with something like:

```
while [[ ! -f ${SOURCEFILE} ]] && [[ $(date +'%s') < ${EndTime} ]]
```