# If condition to check if two strings stored in a variable occur one after other in a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement

> $cat list

```
Hi
welcome
one
two 
good evening

Value1="two"
value2="evening"
```

For above file values, output should be echo "values are present one after the other line"

Need to know the if condition command to check if both variable values occur one after the other in a file.

If both variable values occur one line after other in a file, then echo some statement.

for example:
$cat list
    Hi
    two
    one
    three 
    good evening

in above condition, both variable value are not present one after the other line so output should be echo "values are not present one after the other line"

Comment: You should be able to solve this on your own. This question doesn't belong here. At least click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46036580/edit)** and update the question with some pseudo-code, or code that you tried and failed to run successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to represent multiple conditions in a shell if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826425/how-to-represent-multiple-conditions-in-a-shell-if-statement)

Comment: i still have not tried because not sure how to define if condition for two variables values occurring one after the other in a file..Searched for it but couldn't find any answer

Comment: no..its not for mutiple condition. command should be to detect if both variables are present one after the other line. if they are present, then echo "they are present one after other line" else echo "they are not present one after the other line"

Comment: have edited the question with examples

Comment: There is no magical command that does that. You have to implement some logic there...

Comment: can it be done by detecting line number of both variable and check if both are one after other ?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46036580/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

With awk you could write something like this:

```
awk -F= '$1=="Value1"{l=NR}$1=="value2"&&NR==l+1{print "ok"}' file
```

Comment: Is the sample in the question accurate? When I test it with that sample I get "ok"

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

Value1="two"
value2="evening"

while read line; do
if [[ "$Value1" == *"$line"* ]];then
    read anotherline
    if [[ "$anotherline" == *"$value2"* ]];then
    echo "values are present one after the other line" 
    fi
fi
done < list
```

If you want exact string match then remove `*` wildcards and use single brackets