# Error doing a compound if condition with integers in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to perform a OR operation between two sub AND conditions like as follows.

```
elif [[ $RBIT >= 7000.00 && $RBIT <= 15000.00 ]] || [[ $TBIT >= 7000.00 && $TBIT <= 15000.00 ]]; then
echo #statements;
exit 0;
fi
```

But getting it in error.

```
/script: line 20: syntax error in conditional expression
/script: line 20: syntax error near `7000.00'
/script: line 20: `elif [[ $RBIT >= 7000.00 && $RBIT <= 15000.00 ]] || [[ $TBIT >= 7000.00 && $TBIT <= 15000.00 ]]; then'
```

Of course, the variables RBIT and TBIT has float values with 2 decimal points.

I am confused if I caused a syntax error here or 'if condition' doesn't work like that way. Kindly help.

Comment: The error message doesn't look vanilla.

Comment: @iBug can you clarify?.

Comment: `[[ $TBIT >= 7000.00 && $RBIT <= 15000.00 ]]` in error message but `[[ $TBIT >= 7000.00 && $TBIT <= 15000.00 ]]` in code.

Comment: I think you might want to read some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash You might also be interested in this, although it's kind of moot for floats anyway: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: @iBug: I corrected it in the script, but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash supports only integer math.  So, you could rewrite your condition as:

```
elif ((RBIT >= 7000 && RBIT <= 15000)) || ((TBIT >= 7000 && TBIT <= 15000)); then
```

While dealing with integers, `((...))` is a better construct to use.  And `$` is optional for variable expansion inside `((...))` expression.

---

You may want to see this related posts:

- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces)
- [How to represent multiple conditions in a shell if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826425/how-to-represent-multiple-conditions-in-a-shell-if-statement)
- [Compound if statements with multiple expressions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11267569/6862601)

Comment: I noticed too that downvote. @codeforester, your solution perfectly worked for me. I solved the whole bash script now due to this.