# why use || instead of -o in IF in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

Why/when should I use **||** instead of **-o** in a **IF** statement in BASH?

e.g. `if [ a = a ] || [ b = b ]` instead of `if [ a = a -o b = b ]`.

Comment: See this related post: [How to represent multiple conditions in a shell if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826462/6862601).

Comment: I guess the answer is __||__ for portability?

Comment: The second example you show [can become problematic](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2166).

Comment: Where can I read about this in a clear way for a non-expert? The answer to the original question is too complicated for me.