# in bash when i try to check for null or empty using if statement get syntax error

Tags: bash

In bash when I try to check for null or empty i get syntax error message

```
DEFAULT_VALUE="0"
CRAM_QUERY=$(mycommand) 

if [[ "$CRAM_QUERY" == "NULL" ] || ["$CRAM_QUERY" == ""]] ; then 
   CRAM_QUERY="$DEFAULT_VALUE"
fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent multiple conditions in a shell if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826425/how-to-represent-multiple-conditions-in-a-shell-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```sh
DEFAULT_VALUE="0"
CRAM_QUERY=$(mycommand) 

if [[ "$CRAM_QUERY" == "NULL" || "$CRAM_QUERY" == "" ]] ; then 
   CRAM_QUERY="$DEFAULT_VALUE"
fi
```