# Shell Scripting: How to do multiple conditions in if else statement

Tags: bash, shell

How should I phrase an if statement with multiple conditions:

```
if [ <T/F Condition> ] && [ <T/F Condition> ] && [ <T/F Condition> ]
```

or

```
if [ <T/F Condition> && <T/F Condition> && <T/F Condition>]
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent multiple conditions in a shell if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826425/how-to-represent-multiple-conditions-in-a-shell-if-statement)

Answer (score 1):

As "man test" would've shown you "-a" stands for "and".

eg.:

```
if [ <T/F Condition> -a <T/F Condition> -a <T/F Condition> ]
```

Watch the spacing too.

Comment: I didn't.  Why do you think so?   "[" is a link to "test".

Comment: @djifan23 He's correcting your syntax for your second snippet. But see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D

Comment: @Shawn That link got me WTF'ing, until I read the comments.  ;-)

Comment: ? It seems straightforward... And what comments?

Comment: If you follow the link, the first thing you see is an invalid statement.  A lot of emphasis on what you should NOT do.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, no surprise really, given that the page opens with "This page is a compilation of common mistakes..."

Comment: @ilkkachu  But I was so stupid as to follow the link, which doesn't lead to the page opening, does it?  I assure you, I was surprised.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` is a shell operator, in `cmd1 && cmd2`, it tells the shell to only run the second command if the first succeeds.

So, this works, and does what you want:

```
if [ "$x" = a ] && [ "$y" = b ]; then ...
```

However, in this:

```
if [ "$x" = a && "$y" = b ]; then ...
```

The commands to run would be `[ "$x" = a` and `"$y" = b ]`, the first of which will give an error for the missing `]` argument. (Here, it's good to remember that `[` is a regular command, similar to `echo` or so, it just has a funny name.)

Also, you should avoid this:

```
if [ "$x" = a -a "$y" = b ]; then ...
```

even though it works in some shells in simple cases. This has to do with parsing issues when the variables contain strings like `!` (negation) or others that are operators for `[`. Again, since `[` is a regular command, and not special shell syntax, it can't tell which arguments come from variables and which are hardcoded operators.