# what is ${ } command in shell script(bash)

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Well I learning Shell Script this one thing is annoying me 
I cant find what actually ${ } suppose to do

I google around to found out that ${ } is used for substitution

but what I not able to understand is [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/)

If ${ } is suppose to do a substitution then

```
distro=("redhat" "debian" "gentoo")

echo ${distro[0]}
echo ${distro[2]}

echo ${#distro[@]}
```

How come it running the above code when there isnt any substitution .

I'm wrong on this

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces/2188369#2188369) which discusses curly braces, among other things.

Comment: that is @DennisWilliamson(sorry cant vote it no reputation) I guess the ${ } is a substitution with @ as an exception as i see in the manual referred by -- KarolyHorvath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man bash`, search for `${` with `/\${`, press `n` a couple of time and voila..

> Any element of an array may be referenced using  ${name[subscript]}.

and

> ${#name[subscript]} expands to  the length  of  ${name[subscript]}. If
>   subscript is * or @, the expansion is the number of elements in the
>   array.

Checking the previous paragraphs you will also find this:

> Arrays are assigned to using compound assignments of the form name=(value1
>    ...  valuen), where each value is of the form [subscript]=string.  Indexed
>    array assignments do not require the bracket and subscript.