# Difference between conditional expressions using [ and [[

Tags: bash, syntax, conditional-statements

What's the precise difference between:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
```

and

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];
```

Comment: `[` is (generally) the name of a program. This should help explain some of the differences.

Comment: In bash, `[` is a builtin (try `type [`), but `[` is often an external program as well.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces/2188369#2188369).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html):

> Contrary to `[`, `[[` prevents word splitting of variable values. So, if
>   `VAR="var with spaces"`, you do not need to double quote `$VAR` in a test
>   - eventhough using quotes remains a good habit. Also, `[[` prevents pathname expansion, so literal strings with wildcards do not try to
>   expand to filenames. Using `[[`, `==` and `!=` interpret strings to the
>   right as shell glob patterns to be matched against the value to the
>   left, for instance: `[[ "value" == val* ]]`.

Comment: A small addendum: The abilities like prevention of word splitting and path name expansion are a consequence of the fact that `[[` is a built-in as compared to `[` which is an external command.

Comment: @Samveen: `[` is an external command. But it's also a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

There is none. The `[[`...`]]` syntax introduces some other things you can do with conditional expressions, though. From `help [[`:

```
Returns a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional
expression EXPRESSION.  Expressions are composed of the same primaries used
by the `test' builtin, and may be combined using the following operators:

  ( EXPRESSION )    Returns the value of EXPRESSION
  ! EXPRESSION              True if EXPRESSION is false; else false
  EXPR1 && EXPR2    True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true; else false
  EXPR1 || EXPR2    True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true; else false

When the `==' and `!=' operators are used, the string to the right of
the operator is used as a pattern and pattern matching is performed.
When the `=~' operator is used, the string to the right of the operator
is matched as a regular expression.
```

Comment: There is none, but here are some?

Comment: Yes, there is absolutely no difference between the results of `[ $? -ne 0 ]` and `[[ $? -ne 0 ]]`.