# What is the x variable used for in the example commands below

Tags: bash, command, find

In this post: [Count files and directories using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727069/count-files-and-directories-using-shell-script/13727649#13727649?newreg=022246647846418bafe969b47f438a31), DogBane gave this reply on December 5, 2012:

```
FILECOUNT="$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
DIRCOUNT="$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
```

Can anyone please tell me what the x after -printf means or is used for?

Thank you.

Comment: It is _another_ way to say: `FILECOUNT="$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)"` ... if that helps ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-printf x` will simply print one `x` for each match, with no new-line or anything else (esp. not the filename).

These `find` commands just print one character for each file (or directory) found, and then count the number of characters (`wc -c`).