# Location=$1? what does it mean?

Tags: unix

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCATION=$1
FILECOUNT=0
DIRCOUNT=0

if [ "$#" -lt "1" ]
then
echo "Usage: ./test2.sh <directory>"
exit 0
fi
```

I don't actually get what the If statement is saying can anyone help me to explain this?Thank you

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#POSPARAMREF

Comment: the first parameter passed to the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` refers to the first argument of the bash file. In this case, you can pass your directory path by issuing the following command:

`# ./test2.sh /path/of/your/directory`

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCATION=$1 #first argument of the script
FILECOUNT=0
DIRCOUNT=0

if [ "$#" -lt "1" ] #if the number of argument(s) ($#) is less than 1
then
echo "Usage: ./test2.sh <directory>"
exit 0
fi
```

You can read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/l-bash-parameters/index.html) for more information about parameter passing.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but something i am still not clear that, what does it mean by less than 1? maybe i should show you where i get this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727069/count-files-and-directories-using-shell-script

Comment: It's just checking if there is an argument at all.

Comment: @user3488212 Matthew is right. If there is no argument, the number of argument will zero.

Comment: suppose i typed in ./test2.sh, i want the output to be like this 
Usage: ./test2.sh <directory>, but when i try that only thing i got is ./test2.sh: line 10: [: 1: integer expression expected] ?

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is the first argument that is passed to the bash script. If you start the script like `./test2.sh argument1 argument2` the `$1` will refer `argument1`.

The if-statement checks, if the count of arguments (that's the `$#`) is smaller than 1, then it will output the usage statement (as it seems you can't run the script without any argument).