# If and else, different variables and same result

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, sh

My problem is that i don't understand why when I run the script if i write "yes" or "no" it  always says I'm quitting the script. I know that it doesn't recognise `$reply` and "yes" as  equal but why? (I am new in bash programming). Thanks!

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo 'This script will install: Firefox 17.0.1 (language: enGB or itIT or enUS) and flash 11 in Firefox17.0.1, continue?'
read reply
if (( "$reply" = "yes" )); then
  pkill firefox
  rm -rf /tmp/fox
  mkdir /tmp/fox
  cd /tmp/fox
  rm -rf /opt/firefox/*
  rm -rf /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*
  rm -f /usr/share/icons/mozicon128.png
  mkdir /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
  mkdir /opt/firefox
  echo "Enter your language (exmp: it en us)"
  read reply1
  if (( "$reply1" = "it" )); then
    wget ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/it-IT/firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2
  elif (( "$reply1" = "en" )); then
    wget ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-GB/firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2
  else
    wget ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2
  fi
  wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.258/install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
  wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Mozilla_Nightly_icon_2011.png

  tar -xvf firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2
  tar -xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

  cp -R firefox/* /opt/firefox
  cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
  rm -f /opt/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
  cp -f Mozilla_Nightly_icon_2011.png /opt/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
  echo "Reboot the system to show the new icon?"
  read response
  if (( "$response" = "yes" )); then
    reboot 
  else
    echo 'Installation Complete'
  fi
else
  echo "I'm quitting the script..."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: If you're confused with different parentheses types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces

Comment: As an aside, forcibly removing stuff out of `/usr` is rarely a good idea. Create a package for your pkatform (RPM? Deb? Gentoo? You're not saying) and install it the normal way.

Comment: You need `[[ ]]` not `(( ))` - also +1 for @tripleee - make a package/formula/recipe whatever for you system to handle uninstalling.

Answer (score 6):

You're using an arithmetic expression block `(( ))` to compare strings. Chaos will ensue.

```
read -p 'This script will install: Firefox 17.0.1 (language: enGB or itIT or enUS) and flash 11 in Firefox17.0.1, continue?' reply
if [[ "$reply" = "yes" ]]; then
    …
```

Answer (score 3):

Double parenthesis `(( ... ))`, when used with an `if/then` construct, return an exit status according to the evaluation of the *integer* test expression they are embracing. For instance, the test `((5 == 5))` would evaluate true (i.e. `0`).

Standalone, double parenthesis allow for you to use arithmetic evaluations like `i=$(( 2+3 ))`, and/or c-style syntax, like

```
(( i = 1 )) #or 
(( i++ )) #or 
for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do ...; done
```

However, in your code, while you are trying to evaluate variable comparison expressions, you are in fact testing against a c-style assignment. `(( "$reply" = "yes" ))` does neither compare integers nor any other values, but simply assigns a numerical conversion of the string `"yes"` to a variable identified by the content of `$reply` and returns the assigned value as its exit status.

`yes` converts to `0`. In the case that a user entered `yes` as their reply, the effect will be the assignment

```
yes=0
```

Given that, the `if` statement is merely testing for an integer value to be nonzero, so since the assigned value in the parenthesis is zero, it will return a `1` as an exit code, which means `false`, and the `then` block will not be executed. Unless the user enters a nonzero integer value.

Change parenthesis to double-brackets `[[...]]` and you will be fine. If you prefer to use `=` or `==` as an operator doesn't matter in this case.

```
if [[ "$reply" = "yes" ]]; then
```

You will find useful answers on [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) site when in need for further details.

Comment: How does this add anything to the answer given 8 min ago?

Comment: You're right. If anything, it merely adds a link to a single, yet useful reference. But when I started on writing, there wasn't any answer yet. I must have missed yours being posted.

Comment: Don't downvote correct answers just because they're duplicates. There's no shortage of horrible ones you could be spending your points on.

Comment: @ormaaj Down vote taken back. I always take down votes back if the edits sort the issue. This should be the approach IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, @ormaaj. I also expanded my answer to maybe make it a little bit more useful.

Comment: To be pedantic, a true exit status is 0, not 1: `((5==5)); echo $?`

Comment: @glennjackman that's not pedantry, that's *lifesaving information*.

Comment: Thank you! These explanations/suggestions were very helpful for me. Sorry if the problem was so stupid...

Answer (score 0):

Run this script, It worked for me with no errors and got my flash player working.

```
# Prepare Directory's
pkill firefox
mkdir /tmp/fox
cd /tmp/fox
rm -rf /opt/firefox/*
rm -rf /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*
rm -f /usr/share/icons/mozicon128.png
mkdir /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
mkdir /opt/firefox

# Download Resources
wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-18.0.tar.bz2
wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.258/install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz
wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Mozilla_Nightly_icon_2011.png

# Extract Resources
tar -xvf firefox-18.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

# Install
cp -R firefox/* /opt/firefox
cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
#Restart Backtrack to reload start menu icon's or goto menu editor and reselect icon
cp -f Mozilla_Nightly_icon_2011.png /usr/share/icons/mozicon128.png

# Done
echo 'Installation Complete'
```