# error in Integer comparison in bash

Tags: linux, bash, integer, comparison

I am trying to perform a simple integer comparison in bash, which I am new to using, and my methods are causing an error.  Any advice would be appreciated.

My basic logic is that I am reading in hurricane track points.  There may be multiple entries for the same track_id, with different pressure values.  What I want to do is store only one entry per track_id into the array track_id_poly; the case with the lowest pressure.  So I am looping through each line, and attempting to compare the current pressure (for $int), with the previous track pressure ($int - 1), and if it is lower, replace the previous array value with the new lower pressure.  I hope that makes sense.  My code is below.

```
int=0
    while read track_id ppres_inter 
    do
      printf -v pres_inter "%.0f" "$pres_inter"
      echo pressure $pres_inter
      case $int in
      0)
        Track_id_poly[$int]=$track_id
        Pres_inter_poly[$int]=$pres_inter
        ((int=int+1)) ;;
      *)  
       if [[ $track_id == ${Track_id_poly[$int-1]} ]]
       then
         if (( $pres_inter -lt ${Pres_inter_poly[$int-1]} ))
         then
           Track_id_poly[$int-1]=$track_id
           Pres_inter_poly[$int-1]=$pres_inter
         fi
       else  
         Track_id_poly[$int]=$track_id
         Pres_inter_poly[$int]=$pres_inter
         ((int=int+1))
       fi ;;
      esac
    done <$file_poly
    int_poly=$int
    echo Number of polygon crossings from set $i is $int_poly
```

The line that is causing me problems is the integer comparison for $pres_inter.

```
if (( $pres_inter -lt ${Pres_inter_poly[$int-1]} ))
```

I get the following error:

```
line 41:  96800 -lt 98759 : syntax error in expression (error token is "98759 ")
```

Any tips to fix this problem would be appreciated.  Probably a simple fix!

Comment: Using int as variable name might not be a good idea. Although that's not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `((...))` operator does not accept the same syntax as the `test`, `[..]`, or `[[...]]` commands.  To compare two numbers in `((...))`, you would use actual `>` or `<` symbols:

```
$ (( 4 > 2 )) && echo '4 is bigger!'
4 is bigger!
```

See the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of the `bash(1)` man page for more information (or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic)).

Answer (score 0):

My shell scripting is rusty for good reason but you may to review that line and either use "[[ ]]" instead of "(( ))", or use "<" instead of "-lt" . See [bash: double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces)

However, the main tip I'd give to you is to stop using bash for things that involve anything beyond simple program invocation and switch to a scripting language (Perl, Python, ...) because it won't only be more robust, it'll be easier to get the job done and it'll also run faster.

Answer (score -2):

In bash "((expression))" is differently evaluated. So you cannot use the operator "-lt", instead you can use the normal operator <.

For further info see the man page of bash:

> ((expression))
>
> The  expression is evaluated according to the rules
>   described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the
>   expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return
>   status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

And the paragraph [ARITHMETIC EVALUATION](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) explains further possibilities.