# simple while loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I've started learning bash scripting. I wrote simple while loop, but it doesn't work.
it's say that : command not found.does anybody knows why ?
Here is my code:

```
let x=5; while [$x -lt 10];do echo "x is : $x";let x=$x+1; done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add spaces.

```
while [ $x -lt 10 ];
```

For more information, please see this answer to [How to use double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188223/1508519):

> A single bracket (`[`) usually actually calls a program named `[`; `man
>   test` or `man [` for more info. Example:
>
> ```
> $ VARIABLE=abcdef
> $ if [ $VARIABLE == abcdef ] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
> yes
> ```

Also, this is what `info test` has to say on the matter:

> '`test`' has an alternate form that uses opening and closing square
>   brackets instead a leading '`test`'.  For example, instead of '`test -d
>   /`', you can write '`[ -d / ]`'.  The square brackets must be separate
>   arguments; for example, '`[-d /]`' does not have the desired effect.
>   Since '`test EXPR`' and '`[ EXPR ]`' have the same meaning, only the
>   former form is discussed below.

Therefore, the equivalent would look like:

```
let x=5; while test $x -lt 10;do echo "x is : $x";let x=$x+1; done
```

Comment: Exactly. The conditional `[`...`]` is just a shell command, and like any other command, the command name (`[`) has to be separated from its arguments (`-lt 10 ]`) by space.