# How to you repeatedly execute a command in bash with a loop statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute the command:

```
echo 'Hello World'
```

Ten times, but I don't want to type it out ten times, and I thought I could do it with a loop, but I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple while loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713594/simple-while-loop-in-bash)

Comment: But.... the example there show (after correction) only 5 lines?.....

Comment: @Luuk The loop in the suggested link runs for `x=5` to `9` -- 5 iterations. You'll need to change one or both endpoints of the loop to change the number of iterations.

Comment: Yeah, i know that. but does the asker of this question realize that this is a question for which the answer is easily found?

Answer (score 0):

You seem new to `Bash` loops so I will take some time to explain my approach to this question.

#### Approach

Yes, you can definitely use loops in Bash. And in this example I will use the `for` loop. I will also use the `seq` command. When `seq` receives only one argument, an integer, it will generate numbers 1,2,3 ... until that integer, or in other words until the last number. Since I want `Hello World` printed ten times, I will just specify `10` as the sole argument of `seq`. Note that in this case, the number specified is **inclusive**. More information on the official documentation [here](https://ss64.com/bash/seq.html).

So my code below does basically this: for every number (stated as `i` here) from 1 to 10, print the string `Hello World`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 10)
do
    echo "Hello World"
done
```

And it is basically the same as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
do
    echo "Hello World"
done
```