# Double parenthesis with and without dollar

Tags: bash

Is `$(...)` the same as `(...)` in Bash?

Also, is `$((...))` the same as `((...))`?

Also, is `${...}` the same as `{...}`?

More generally what does the dollar sign stand for? Thank you.

Comment: For a more comprehensive answer see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html.  For example $ in regex context means end of line. Generally $var gives the value of var.  Considering var as a reference to (or name of) a value, such as in var=value, $var dereferences var to produce the value it references and can be considered as the dereference operator in contexts where it prefixes a reference.

Comment: `tldp.org` isn't a great source for Bash related things because the site has many errors and misleading information.

Comment: Related post: [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces).

Answer (score 232, accepted):

In the following, I use "returns" to indicate return values and "produces" to indicate "substitutes the resulting text."

- [`$(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) means execute the command in the parens in a subshell and produces its stdout.  Example:

  ```
    $ echo "The current date is $(date)"
    The current date is Mon Jul  6 14:27:59 PDT 2015
  ```
- [`(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) means run the commands listed in the parens in a subshell.  Example:

  ```
    $ a=1; (a=2; echo "inside: a=$a"); echo "outside: a=$a"
    inside: a=2
    outside: a=1
  ```
- [`$((...))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html)  means perform arithmetic and produce the result of the calculation.  Example:

  ```
    $ a=$((2+3)); echo "a=$a"
    a=5
  ```
- `((...))` means perform arithmetic, possibly changing the values of shell variables, but don't produce its result.  Example:

  ```
    $ ((a=2+3)); echo "a=$a"
    a=5
  ```

  Note that the return value of the calculation *is* returned, so it can be used in `while` or `if`.
- [`${...}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) means produce the value of the shell variable named in the braces.  Example:

  ```
    $ echo ${SHELL}
    /bin/bash
  ```
- [`{...}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) means execute the commands in the braces as a group.  Example:

  ```
    $ false || { echo "We failed"; exit 1; }
    We failed
  ```

> More generally what does the dollar sign stand for?

It means whatever it means in the given context.

Comment: At least for `((...))` and `(...)`, you can think of the dollar-prefixed version as working the same as the statement, but expanding to the output (where the "output" of `((...))` is the arithmetic result. There's a more subtle analogy for `{...}`; in each case, they group their contents away from their surroundings. Think `${foo}_bar` vs `$foo_bar` and `echo foo; echo bar > /dev/null` vs `{ echo foo; echo bar; } > /dev/null`.

Comment: Excellent answer, except for that last paragraph: The `$` sign invariably signifies an *expansion*. I.e., based on what comes after the `$` (like `((`, `(`, `{`, etc.) some string value is computed *and the `$...` expression is replaced with the computed string*.

Comment: There is difference between _output_ and _returned result_. Purpose of `((...))` is to return result, but it does not print output and $((...)) prints output but does not return result. That's why ((...)) can be used as a condition: `if ((1 == 1)); then echo OK; fi` or `((1 == 1)) && echo OK`. Another difference, the ((...)) is bashism, $((...)) is POSIX

Comment: Please check the edit `queue` if possible.

Comment: Note also that parens are also used to set the value of a variable as a bash array, e.g. `MYARRAY=(element1 element2 element3)`

Comment: Perhaps we could think of `$` as a dereferencing operation. For example `echo $var` and `echo $(func)` are bash equivalents to C's `*var` and `*func()`. Though I don't know if that approximation is consistent with `$'some\n odd \n string'`

Comment: I would also like to emphasize, that while commands in `() ` are executed in the subshell, commands in `{}` are executed in the current shell context (no subshell is created). `a=1; (a=2; echo "inside: a = $a"); echo "outside: a = $a"` gives us _inside: a = **2** outside: a = **1**_, and `a=1; { a=2; echo "inside: a= $a"; }; echo "outside: a=$a"` gives us _inside: a= **2** outside: a= **2**_.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the answer above:

1. `[..]` is used in conditions or logical expressions. Example:

```
$ VAR=2
$ if [ $VAR -eq 2 ]

> then
> echo 'yes'
> fi
yes
```

2. `[[...]]` offers extended functionality to single square brackets. Particularly, it is useful for =~ operator (used in regular expressions). Example:

```
$ VAR='some string'
$ if [[ $VAR =~ [a-z] ]]; then
> echo 'is alphabetic'
> fi
is alphabetic
```

Reference:

> https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-parenthesis-explained