# When the input is entered as "N", it returns "YES", what could be the problem?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
read -n1 input

if (($input == "y")) || (($input == "Y"))
then
echo "YES"
elif (($input == "n")) || (($input == "N"))
then
echo "NO"
fi
```

When the input is entered as "N", it returns "YES", what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

you should use simple square brackets to test if something is true. double parenthesis are for arithmetic:

```
if [ "$input" = "y" ] || [ "$input" = "Y" ]
```

Notes:

- put double quotes around your variables
- put spaces before and after the brackets
- use `=` instead of `== (bash and some other shells allow == as a synonym, but it's not portable)` (thanks @GordonDavisson)

Some related questions:

- [Double parenthesis with and without dollar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255699/double-parenthesis-with-and-without-dollar/31255942)
- [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba)

Comment: Error (stderr)
Solution.sh: line 3: [Y: command not found
Solution.sh: line 3: [Y: command not found
Solution.sh: line 6: [Y: command not found
Solution.sh: line 6: [Y: command not found

Comment: you need to put spaces before and after your brackets

Comment: In a `[ ]` test expression, you should double-quote variable references (i.e. `"$input"` instead of just `$input`) to avoid weird parsing, and use `=` instead of `==` (bash and some other shells allow `==` as a synonym, but it's not portable).

Answer (score 3):

Use `[` / `]` (which tests for logic expressions) instead of `((` / `))` (which is used to evaluate arithmetic expressions):

```sh
read -n1 input

if [ "$input" = "y" ] || [ "$input" = "Y" ]
then
echo "YES"
elif [ "$input" = "n" ] || [ "$input" = "N" ]
then
echo "NO"
fi
```

---

Side note: There is a neat workaround to make a case-insensitive comparison:

```sh
read -n1 input

if [ "${input,,}" = "y" ]
then
echo "YES"
elif [ "${input,,}" = "n" ]
then
echo "NO"
fi
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged `bash` as well as `sh`: in `bash` it's [usually better](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) to use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: its useless, it dont work like that, thank you for quick reply

Comment: i need a solution with paratesis

Comment: @SelmanKeskin please update the question with these additional details, eg, why does the answer need to use parenthesis? is this a class/homework assignment? (and if so, what are the detailed instructions of the assignment?)

Comment: thank you for professional answer, its worked

Comment: In a `[ ]` test expression, you should double-quote variable references (i.e. `"$input"` instead of just `$input`) to avoid weird parsing, and use `=` instead of `==` (bash and some other shells allow `==` as a synonym, but it's not portable).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, you're absolutely right! I did both of those in the second "optimized" code. I wanted to leave OP's code as-is and just correct the `((` / `))`.  I updated the answer now. Thank you!