# Java Input error: Syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: java

Trying to create a Prime Number Tester like the code below but when I input `java isPrime(9)` in the terminal window, I get

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I want the code to read either `true` or `false` back to me.

Can someone also explain to me the function of the `main method` as I guess my user input is first captured by the `main method` and then passed on to any other referenced methods. Or is it a matter of placement of the `main method` in the code, that is to put the `main method` at the top (or is this irrelevant in java)?

Here is the code.

```
public class isPrime {

public static boolean isPrime(int N){
    for (int i=3; i == N/2; i++){
        if (N%i==0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(isPrime(N));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run it with :

```
java isPrime 9
```

The command line arguments are not passed within parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Why does `java isPrime(9)` cause an error? Well, the bash shell treats `()` specially. To know more, read the answer to this question - [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces).

You could quote the brackets to force bash to drop its special treatment of `()`. Something like `java 'isPrime(9)'`. But this prints another error: `Error: Could not find or load main class isPrime(9)`.

What just happened? The java command expects to be invoked as `java [options] MainClass [arg1 arg2 arg3...]`. The first word after `java` that does not begin with a `-` is the class to execute. Rest of the words in the command line are made available as `args[]` in the `main(String []args)` function.

So, if you want to execute the code in `isPrime` class with an input of 9, the correct syntax would be `java isPrime 9`.