# Usage of parenthesis in bash

Tags: bash, parentheses

I saw this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces) question regarding the use of parentheses in bash.

Great piece of information but I still have a couple of doubts about how to use parentheses. For instance the below code :

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
b=6
c=7
$(( d = a * b + c ))
echo "d : "$d
```

gave me the output :

```
./parantheses: line 5: 37: command not found
d : 37
```

and my research about `$(( ))` lead me to this [site](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html) which gave me below piece of information.

> $(( expression ))
>  
>   The expression is treated as if it were within
>   double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses is not
>   treated specially. All tokens in the expression undergo parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and quote removal. Arithmetic
>   substitutions can be nested.

I didn't quite get it :( 
But I did understand that we don't have to use `$` before every variable and that the variables will automatically be substituted. What more is to it and why my script is throwing an error?

Also what does `a=$( expression )` do?

Does this one too work like `$(( ))`?

Kindly illustrate the answers with examples so that I can understand better.

**Note :** I ran the above script in cygwin.

Comment: What is your `$SHELL`?

Comment: It is bash, but please keep in mind that I'm running a cygwin.

Comment: One question at a time. search for `$( expression )`, or post a separate question (please don't... find a duplicate).

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2084)

Comment: Thankyou for the introducing shellcheck.. Cool indeed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(( d = a * b + c ))
```

After the calculations, what's left is a number, and since that's the first word, the shell will try to execute it, as a command. Not surprisingly, there's no commmand named `37`.

You can ignore the result:

```
: $(( d = a * b + c ))
```

But it's better to simply write what you meant:

```
d=$(( a * b + c ))
```

Comment: how about `$( )`. How is it different from `$(( ))`?

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. I was searching for this indeed. I never knew that `$(..)` superceeded `backticks`.  In fact  I mastered Linux using an old Linux Bible ;) Thankyou pal !!