# Don't seem to understand bash's if correctly

Tags: bash

I am busy making a function that gives the user a yes or no question. However I seem to be making a mistake with my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Test, enter y or n: " choice
echo "$choice"
if [ "$choice"==y ]
then
  echo "you choose $choice"
else
  echo "you did not choose y"
fi
```

This always seems to return `You choose y|n`, despite the fact that I expect it to return `you did not choose y`.

I have been searching for a while now and tried to solve it using double brackets, no brackets, quotes, no quotes.

Comment: `[[ "$choice" == "y" ]]`

Comment: Please don't make scripts interactive without compelling reason; it is not the unix way to invoke programs. Far better is to have a command line option like `my_program -y`.

Comment: @msw that is my intention but for the sake of this example i put it like this, as i discovered that my problem was specifically in this part of the code, no need to put extra 'useless' code here

Comment: There are FAQs, and then there are things where **literally exactly this bug** is shown on the tag wiki page, in an example of how to take a bad question and improve it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Excuse me, I did not see that page, if I did I would not have asked the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a syntax error, you weren't correctly using the operator ==.
You must put spaces around your operator.
Good practice : put quotes around y so you know it's a literal value and use = rather than == for compatibility reason :

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Test, enter y or n: " choice
echo "$choice"
if [ "$choice" = "y" ]
then
  echo "you choose $choice"
else
  echo "you did not choose y"
fi
```

I didn't find any satisfying sources, here's is the best I could find :

- https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces)
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-basic-operators.htm

Comment: `must double the [] ` , is incorrect. `missing the quotes around y` also incorrect, `your y is a name but you must use the litteral value "y"`, also incorrect. `put spaces around your operator`, is correct and the only problem with OP's code.

Comment: Well it did work for me. waiting to accept the answer. Would be nice if you could tell me why and/or point me to some reference

Comment: Well, I partly disagree with you 123. It's true that op didn't need all the changes I suggested but it did what OP was trying to do. If you don't put quotes around y, you're not doing a litteral match. For the rest, you're totally right, my bad.

Comment: `If you don't put quotes around y, you're not doing a litteral match`, yes you are, the quotes literally do nothing unless you are using special characters.

Comment: Not really any reason to use `==` instead of `=` as it only breaks compatibility with other POSIX shells.

Comment: @123 As far as I understand, literal matching means you don't interpret special characters, either there are some or not. I get your point, y would have worked as good as "y" here but it doesn't mean you're doing a literal match. The source I provide specifically explains only "text" does literal matching and no quotes does not.

Comment: With `[ ... ]`, you *always* perform a literal match of whatever appears on the right-hand side of the `=`. The shell might have expanded the original argument before `[` runs, but that's a separate issue. With `[[ ... = ...]]` (`=` or `==`), the right-hand side is treated as a pattern if it is unquoted.

Comment: @chepner Please, explain me this line then : 
[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
It comes from the source I provide and I don't understand it but it really gives me the impression it is not literal matching. I'd really like to understand as it seems I miss the point.

Comment: The shell expands `z*` to any matching files before `[` runs. If the current directory has two files `za` and `zb`, then `[` gets 4 arguments; `==`, `za`, `zb`, and `]`. It only gets the argument `z*` if there are no matching files, in which case the shell leaves the pattern unexpanded. `[[ ... ]]`, on the other hand, is a special shell construct, not a regular command. `[[ $foo == z* ]]` compares the value of `$foo` to the pattern `z*`, rather than performing pathname expansion on the pattern first.

Comment: @chepner Ok, so your point is that it is still a literal match because the shell provides arguments which are used as literal values by the bash script, am I right? If yes, thanks for the explanation. Actually, thanks anyway.

Comment: That is correct. `[` is treated the same as any other command regarding its arguments (it's easier to see if you think of it as `test $a = z*` instead). `[[` operates under a separate set of rules.

Comment: Please consider using a better reference than the ABS -- it has a longstanding and unfortunate habit of showcasing bad practices in its examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces around == and it will work.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Test, enter y or n: " choice
echo "$choice"
if [ "$choice" == y ]
then
  echo "you choose $choice"
else
  echo "you did not choose y"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to quote the second string `"y"` and put spaces between string1, the operator and string2.

```
[…]
if [ "$choice" == "y" ]
[…]
```

You don't have to double the square brackets.

Comment: Quoting `y` isn't necessary, and `==` should not be used with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: I know, that you don't have to quote. But in my opinion it is good practice to quote every string or character.

Comment: Then don't say "you just have to quote the second string".