# Read string and convert to INT (BASH)

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

I have a simple script in Bash to read a number in a file and then compare it with a different threshold. The output is this:

```
: integer expression expected
: integer expression expected
OK: 3
```

My code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget=$(wget http://10.228.28.8/ -O /tmp/wget.txt 2>/dev/null)
output=$(cat /tmp/wget.txt | awk 'NR==6')
#output=7
echo $output

if [ $output -ge 11 ];then
    echo "CRITICAL: $output"
    exit 2
elif [ $output -ge 6 ] && [ $output -lt 11 ];then
    echo "WARNING: $output"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK: $output"
    exit 0
fi

rm /tmp/wget.txt
```

I know what is the problem, I know that I'm reading a string and I try to compare a int. But I don't know how can I do to read this file and convert the number to read in a int var..

Any ideas?

Comment: No the problem is that you forgot to quote.

Comment: Sorry its my first post and i dont know how to use. Thanks anyways for your help ;)

Comment: @hectormarina : At what line are you getting the error?

Comment: And what is the content of `/tmp/wget.txt` after you run `wget`?

Comment: I suspect your `wget.txt` has DOS line-endings...

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. More relevantly to understanding your immediate bug, so is `set -x` (or `bash -x yourscript`); if either includes `$'\r'` in your contents, you have confirmation of the DOS-newline theory.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs when `$output` is the empty string; whether or not you quote the expansion (and you should), you'll get the integer expression required error. You need to handle the empty string explictly, with a default value of zero (or whatever default makes sense).

```
wget=$(wget http://10.228.28.8/ -O /tmp/wget.txt 2>/dev/null)
output=$(awk 'NR==6' < /tmp/get.txt)
output=${output:-0}

if [ "$output" -ge 11 ];then
  echo "CRITICAL: $output"
  exit 2
elif [ "$output" -ge 6 ];then
  echo "WARNING: $output"
  exit 1
else
  echo "OK: $output"
  exit 0
fi
```

(If you reach the `elif`, you already know the value of `$output` is less than 11; there's no need to check again.)

---

The problem also occurs, and is consistent with the error message, if `output` ends with a carriage return. You can remove that with

```
output=${output%$'\r'}
```

Comment: But if you watch his output it prints `OK: 3` which is the `echo "OK: $output"` in the `else` condition. So `$output` is not empty

Comment: You could eliminate the extra variable assignment by putting things into awk.  `output=$(awk 'NR==6{printf("%d",$1)}') /tmp/wget.txt`

Comment: Ah, true. I bet the output of `OK: $output=` would be enlightening, though. There is probably a carriage return at the end of the value.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of suggestions from my side regarding your code.

You could explicitly tell bash the `output` is an integer

```
declare -i output # See [1]
```

Change

```
output=$(cat /tmp/wget.txt | awk 'NR==6') # See [2]
```

may be better written as

```
output=$(awk 'NR==6' /tmp/wget.txt )
```

Change

```
if [ $output -ge 11 ]
```

to

```
if [ "0$output" -ge 11 ] # See [4]
```

or

```
if (( output >= 11 )) # Better See [3]
```

---

**References**

1. Check bash [[ declare ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html).
2. Useless use of cat. Check [[ this ]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)
3. Quoting [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188369/1620779) answer :

   `((...))` enable you to omit the dollar signs on integer and array variables and include spaces around operators for readability. Also empty variable automatically defaults to 0 in such a statement.
4. The zero in the beginning of `"0$output"` help you deal with empty `$output`

   ---

<sup>**Interesting**

`Useless use of cat` is a phrase that has been resounding in SO for long. Check [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+useless+use+of+cat)

[[ @chepner ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) has dealt with the empty `output` fiasco using [[ bash parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in his [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397307/1620779), worth having a look at.</sup>

Comment: Quotes should be used, but they won't help in the current situation, where `$output` is empty. `(( output >= 11))` will work, since an empty variable automatically defaults to 0 in such a statement.

Comment: @chepner: Thankyou, rectified.

Comment: If `$output` is empty, you can replace it with zero using `${output:-0}`.

Comment: @ghoti : The other answer already mention that approach. Is there an obvious disadvantage with my method?

Comment: @sjsam : Setting `output` to zero if it is not set seem the most sensibel approach here.

Comment: @sjsam, your approach is fine if there's 100% confidence that $output will always be an integer (and therefore interpreted correctly by `[ $output -ge ...` etc.)  In my own shell programming, I always strive to add error handling so that if inputs are not structured as expected, we can detect and perhaps control the behaviour rather than just failing. Your reference #3 is great, but perhaps it would be even better to throw an error and warning if `$output` is empty. Since the script in the Q looks like a Nagios script, then perhaps a null/empty value should return an `UNKNOWN` response.

Comment: @ghoti : Appreciate the time. Hope my link to \@chepner's answer will help me not posting the redundant content in this one and I hope the op will pay attention to that answer and your comment above. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simplified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget=$(wget http://10.228.28.8/ -O /tmp/wget.txt 2>/dev/null)
output=$(awk 'NR==6' </tmp/wget.txt )

output="$(( 10#${output//[^0-9]} + 0 ))"

(( output >= 11 )) && { echo "CRITICAL: $output"; exit 2; }
(( output >=  6 )) && { echo  "WARNING: $output"; exit 1; }
echo "OK: $output"
```

The key line to cleanup any input is:

```
output="$(( 10#${output//[^0-9]} + 0 ))"
```

`${output//[^0-9]}`   Will leave only digits from 0 to 9 (will remove all non-numeric chars).

`10#${output//[^0-9]}` Will convert `output` to a base 10 number.

That will correctly convert numbers like `0019`

`"$(( 10#${output//[^0-9]} + 0 ))"` Will produce a zero for a missing value.

Then the resulting number stored in output will be compared to limits and the corresponding output will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

In BASH, It is a good idea to use double brackets for strings:

```
if [[ testing strings ]]; then
    <whatever>
else
    <whatever>
fi
```

Or double parenthesis for integers:

```
if (( testing ints )); then
    <whatever>
else
    <whatever>
fi
```

For example try this:

```
var1="foo bar"
if [ $var1 == 'foo bar' ]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Result:

```
$ bash: [: too many arguments
```

Now, this:

```
var2="foo bar"
if [[ $a == "foo bar" ]]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Result:

```
ok
```

For that, your code in BASH:

```
if [[ $output -ge 11 ]]; then
    echo "CRITICAL: $output"
    exit 2
elif [[ $output -ge 6 ]]; then
    echo "WARNING: $output"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK: $output"
    exit 0
fi
```