# Using --include=GLOB vs ~/path/*.{x,y} with grep

Tags: regex, bash, unix, ubuntu, grep

Trying to identify the difference between the two methods.

I recently had to find a the string `abcABC` in `~/path/`. In that same directory were the subdirectories `~/path/files/` and `~/path/docs/` along with a series of `.h`, `.cpp` and `.txt` files. I only needed to look in the `~/path/` level so using:

`grep -r -i abcABC ~/path/` produced findings in subdirectories which I didn't want.

Using the `*` wildcard to extend the path to be `~/path/*.*/` allowed me to use:

`grep -i abcABC ~/path/*.*` which found the subdirectories and files. However, I needed further refinement to only look at the `.h` and `.cpp` files for `abcABC`.

Did some reading in `man grep` and learned about `--include=GLOB` and altered my command to the following:

`grep -i --include \*.h --include \*.cpp abcABC ~/path/*.*`

This worked, but then I tried (for S&G's) the following:

`grep -i abcABC ~/path/*.{h,cpp}` and produced the same results I needed.

What I would like to know is what does `{ }` do for `grep`? `man grep` puts `{n,m}` in repetition but I am not sure how doing this method equates to `--include=GLOB`.

**EDIT:**  Last response by Jordan gives great detailed Wikipedia example. The duplicate (slightly) problem provides great use case.

Comment: `{}` doesn't do anything for grep. Your shell expands it before sending the arguments to grep. The reason you see a `\ ` in `--include \*.h` (for example) is to escape `*` so your shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I knew that `\` escapes the `*` so that it no longer makes it special and turns it into a regex.

If `{ }` isn't specific to `grep`, then is there a name for it? Is this `GLOB` or "globbing"? What is the functionality?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: Read that early but saw no mention of the `{ }` metacharacters. Curious to know what they functionality is, are they simply a bin for a range of options?

Comment: "Some shells (such as the C shell and Bash) support additional syntax known as alternation or [brace expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_expansion)."

Comment: ... e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188369/2877364).