# "integer expression expected" error

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to write a greeting script. What I have so far:

```
if [ "$HOUR" -lt 12 ]; then
    echo " Good Morning Mohamed"
elif [ "$HOUR" -ge 12 ] && [ "$HOUR" -lt 16 ]; then
    echo " Good Afternoon Jama."
elif [ "$HOUR" -ge 16 ]; then
    echo " Good Evening Jama."  
fi
```

This give me an error

> integer expression expected

How can I fix this?

Comment: `HOUR` is the empty string. See the duplicate.

Comment: So what do i do, do i have to declare a string variable.

Comment: You have to assign some numeric value to `HOUR`. It's either empty or a string, but it's impossible to tell without the rest of your script. If this is your complete script, then it's obviously the empty string.

Comment: If you don't want to set `HOUR` and want the code to still work, you can use `if (( HOUR > 12 )); then ...` construct.  Look at this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8552128/6862601

Comment: brackets ain't working.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, it works if you just give HOUR a value (at least on my CentOS 6 system):

```
HOUR=`date +%k`
if [ "$HOUR" -lt 12 ]; then
    echo " Good Morning Mohamed"
elif [ "$HOUR" -ge 12 ] && [ "$HOUR" -lt 16 ]; then
    echo " Good Afternoon Jama."
elif [ "$HOUR" -ge 16 ]; then
    echo " Good Evening Jama."  
fi
```