# How to store a condition in a variable and evaluate it with eval?

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I am trying to store a condition for comparing values in a variable but it is not working.
The code I have written is :

```
read op
if [ $op == "desc" ]
then
compare='${arr[0]} -gt ${arr[1]}'
if [ eval "$compare" ]
then
 echo "SWAP"
 fi
fi
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, the POSIX-standard string comparison operator is `=`, not `==`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 2):

The right way to write your `eval` statement is:

```
if eval [ "$compare" ]
then
   ...
```

Don't use variables to store a command - see [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).  You can rewrite your code as:

```
read op
if [ "$op" = "desc" ]; then
  if [ "${arr[0]}" -gt "${arr[1]}" ]; then
    echo "SWAP"
  fi
fi
```

Notes:

- it's important to quote your variables inside `[ ]` to prevent word splitting and globbing
- use [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) to validate your code

---

See also:

- [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces)
- [Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: depending on the user input the condition will change . so I was thinking if storing it in a variable rather than writing the loop multiple times.

Comment: Use a `case` statement in such a situation, with explicit `if` statements and without any indirection or `eval`.  That would be more readable and less error prone.

Comment: @DevendraRawat, ...do read the link to BashFAQ #50 -- if you have code you want to avoid repeating, keeping that code in a function is generally the right choice. `mycompare() { [ "${arr[0]}" -gt "${arr[1]}" ]; }` will define the function, which can thereafter be used as `if mycompare; then`.

Answer (score 0):

Given what the code does, `eval` isn't needed and this would be enough:

```
read op ; [ "$op" = "desc" ] && [ "${arr[0]}" -gt "${arr[1]}" ] && echo "SWAP"
```

(The above is functionally equivalent to [codeforester's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022858/6136214).)