# Testing whether any files are older than 7 days

Tags: bash, find

I have a script that finds files in a folder and deletes them if they are older than 7 days. However, I have a little issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUPDIR=/home/vagrant/script/aerospike_backups
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
LOGPATH=/tmp/logs.txt
ADMINACC=email@example.com
EMEIL=rybka@gl.com
#Let's check existing backups, and if it's older than 7 days delete
find_old () {
     if [ -z $(find $BACKUPDIR -mtime +7 -print ) ]
       then
            return 10
              else
find $BACKUPDIR -mtime +7 -delete && echo "Backups deleted at $HOSTNAME on $TIMESTAMP" >  $LOGPATH

fi
}
```

And if I execute this script with empty $BACKUPDIR from terminal use ./scriptname, then type echo $? the shell outputs 10 code as expected because there's not files which is older 7 days or there's just no files at all.

But after I add more if condition like

```
if [[ $(find_old | echo $?) -gt 0 ]]
then
echo "Script return error code"
else
echo "all is ok"
```

The script gives me the output `all is ok`, but it really shouldn't?  What's wrong?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You can get your script checked at [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net)

Answer (score 6):

It's much better to store the found files in an array and then delete them, rather than calling `find` twice - that way, we are guaranteed to delete the exact set of files that we found, in addition to being much more efficient.

```
find_old() {
    while read -r -d '' file; do                  # read the output of find one file at a time
      files+=("$file")                            # append to the array
    done < <(find "$BACKUPDIR" -mtime +7 -print0) # generate NUL separated list of files
    if ((${#files[@]} == 0)); then
      # no files found
      return 10
    else
      printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 rm -f --
    fi
}
```

And then, call your function as:

```
find_old; exit_code=$?
if ((exit_code > 0)) {
  echo "Script returned error code $exit_code"
else
  echo "All is OK"
fi
```

I have fixed a few issues in your code:

- it is important to quote your variables while expanding them.  for example: `find "$BACKUPDIR"` instead of `find $BACKUPDIR`
- `if [[ $(find_old | echo $?) -gt 0 ]]` is not the way to check the exit code of the function; you need to check `$?` directly

---

See also:

- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/6862601)
- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)
- [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290320/6862601)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188199/6862601)

Comment: Only caveat here is that if your file list is longer than will fit on one command line this could fail. Might `printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 rm -f --`

Comment: Also, we're right now ignoring any erroneous exit status from `rm`. Better to leave out the `return 0` and let success or failure from `rm` be passed through.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Thanks Charles!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).