# expr and if in bash

Tags: bash, comparison, arithmetic-expressions

What's wrong with this code? If I input the number **25**, it output **failed** instead of **lol**. Am I missing something?

```
read -p "Enter number : " num
if [ `expr $num > 5` ] 
then 
echo "lol" 
else 
echo "failed" 
fi
```

Comment: See: [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188199/6862601).

Comment: Also see: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/201820) on Unix & Linux SE and [Is double square brackets preferable over single square brackets in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601).

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
if [ `expr $num > 5` ]
```

actually does not do want you think. It will run `expr $num > 5`, so evaluate parameter and redirect the out to a file named `5` ("put 25 in a file named 5") and `if` will evaluate the return code of the previous expression.

If the code if meant to check evaluate if a number is bigger than 5, replace

```
if [ `expr $num > 5` ]
```

with

```
[ "$num" -gt 5 ]
```

`-gt` stands for `greater than`

Comment: `if` does not evaluate the return code of the previous expression. What makes it fail here is that the `expr` output is redirected to the filename `5` thus `expr` does not output anything to stdout. If the call were `expr $num + 5` the code would echo `"lol"`

Comment: You are missing a space: `[ "$num" -gt 5 ]`.

Comment: Only `$num` is the parameter; the output of `expr 25` will be written to a file named `5`.

Answer (score 4):

@babtistemm's answer gives you the suggested solution but in case you insist on using (the bit oldish) `expr` for some reason:

```
read -p "Enter number : " num
if expr "$num" '>' 5 >/dev/null
    then 
        echo "lol" 
    else 
        echo "failed" 
fi
```

Notes:

1. You need to quote `>` so that the shell does not interpret it as redirecting the `stdout`. You could also use `\>`.
2. It is good practice to add double quotes to `$num` as well, so that `expr` will interpret it as *one* expression, thus limiting the chances of a very bad bug or a malicious user hacking your program. (Best would be to do a sanity-check on `$num` before using it, e.g. checking if it is an integer.)
3. This solution necessitates calling a new process, `expr`, which costs a lot more resource from the OS than using the `test` shell command only.
4. If you omit the `>/dev/null`, you will also get a `0` or `1` printed (meaning `false` or `true`), the `stdout` of `expr`. But independently of that, `expr` sets its exit status, `$?` according to the result of the expression, which is tested then by the `if`. (A side remark: if you try to `echo $?` after calling `expr`, it may come at a surprise first that `$? = 0` means true/success as exit status, and `$? != 0` means false by convention.)

Comment: It might also be a good idea to sanity check your input, so that user-supplied data can't generate syntactically invalid code (which might be vulnerable to exploits). For example: `if expr "${num}" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' && expr "$num" '>' 5 >/dev/null; then`

Comment: For sure, the above code is 100% vulnerable. I fear that a malevolent user could execute any code under the script's privileges even if you quote the first operand as `"$num"`.

Comment: @ghoti You’re right about the quotes but I think the regex is overkill for OP's issue.

Comment: @tif unless `expr` exposes a way to execute code, if the parameter is quoted than you are safe from attacks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use an arithmetic expression in bash:

```
if (( num > 5 )); then ...
```

In the manual, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

Answer (score 1):

## Same in a short line:

```
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num
(( num > 5 )) && echo lol || echo fail
```

could be condensed:

```
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num;((num>5))&&echo lol||echo fail
```

This syntaxe will work if first command success!

```
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num
((num > 5)) && {
      echo lol
      /bin/wrongcommand
      :
 } || echo fail
```

Could output:

```
lol
bash: /bin/wrongcommand: No such file or directory
```

But no `fail` because of `:` (is an alias for `true`) will alway success.

You could of course group command for *fail*:

```
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num
((num > 5)) && {
      echo lol
      /bin/wrongcommand
      :
 } || {
      echo fail
      other command
 }
```

Could be written:

```
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num;((num>5))&&{ echo lol;/bin/wrongcommand;:;}||{ echo fail;other command;}
```

You could group commands between `{`  and `;}` (care about the space after first `{`!)

```
Enter a number: 4
fail
bash: other: command not found

Enter a number: 7
lol
bash: /bin/wrongcommand: No such file or directory
```