# Print a comparison output in bash as a boolean value

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question

```
a=1
b=2
```

I want the comparison output to a variable. ie in windows languages you can write something like this. it should print `false`

```
print ($a == $b)
```

tries these below in console.

```
echo $a -eq $b
echo (( $a -eq $b ))
echo "$a" -eq "$b"
c= $(expr  "$a" -eq "$b"  )
echo $c
```

Comment: `[ $a -eq $b ];c=$?`

Comment: @IporSircer. Eventhough it looks so complex . it works !!! thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use arithmetic expansion.

```
echo $(( a == b ))
```

This will print 1 if the expression is true and 0 if the expression is false. No need to add `$` before variable names, you can use operators like in C language and the spaces can be omitted. See [Bash reference manual:Shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) for more info.

Having it to print a string "true" or "false" is a bit more tricky. Usually I go with the same as @Inian, but using `if ... then .. else ... fi` because I usually code under `set -euo pipefail`:

```
if (( a == b )); then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

but we can be smart and do an array:

```
to_bool[0]="false"
to_bool[1]="true"
echo ${to_bool[ a == b ]}
```

but I see no difference then printing just `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `bash` does *not* natively support a `bool` type operator. All the commands/built-ins return an exit code to the shell depending upon its success/failure status. A code `0` to the shell means the operation is success and any non-zero would represent a failure.

So in `bash`, you do the comparison and need to set the `bool` strings explicitly, something like

```
[[ $a == $b ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Note that using `echo true` should not confused with the built-ins `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` which explicitly set the exit code to the shell to `0` and `1` respectively. The `echo` statement just prints out the string mentioned to the standard output.

Also note that `[[` is a shell keyword extension to the POSIX-ly available `[` construct. The former is a added to the bourne again shell and may *not* available in other POSIX compliant shells. If you are looking for a portable way of doing this, use the `[` with the `case` construct as

```
[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
case $? in
    0) printf '%s\n' "true" ;;
    *) printf '%s\n' "false" ;;
esac
```

Comment: I don't see a case for `case` when you are examining the result code of a command. The `if` statement does this naturally and idiomatically. Perhaps see also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to do it in bash directly.

But you can do something as the following based on the return code of the comparison operator:

```
res=0; [ "$s1" == "$s2" ] && res=1
echo $res
```

It sets `res` to zero first and then only if the comparison succedes sets the `res` variable to `1`.

Alternatively, something more concise is the following:

```
[ $s1 -eq $s2 ]; echo $((!$?))
```

which literally prints the return code of the previously executed command. Note the `!` not operator applied to the return code as `0` usually means success i.e. in this case the variable are the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you need it to be POSIX-compliant:

```bash
test $a -ne $b && printf 'false'; return 1
```

Comment: This will `return 1` regardless of the comparison. You can fix it with a pair of braces.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion is in POSIX, though if you need compatibility back to pre-POSIX shells, `[` is probably the most natural operator.

Comment: When following the comments suggestions, probably better no do this as a one-liner. You could do a `if-else` instead.