# Why do I need to use quotes for -n but not for -z?

Tags: bash

My understanding is that `-n` is the opposite of `-z`.

## Testing `-z`...

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo bar
fi
```

```sh
$ ./test1.sh
bar

$ ./test1.sh foo
```

**Works as expected!**

## Testing `-n`...

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ -n $1 ]; then
  echo bar
fi
```

```sh
$ ./test1.sh
bar

$ ./test1.sh foo
bar
```

**Does not work as expected unless I use quotes... Why?**

Trying to figure out when to use quotes and when I can safely omit them.

## Testing `-n` (with quotes)...

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ -n $1 ]; then
  echo bar
fi
```

```sh
$ ./test1.sh

$ ./test1.sh foo
bar
```

**Works as expected!**

Comment: Use `[[ ... ]]` and no need to quote

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, is it bad practice to use `[[]]` then? Trying to thoroughly understand when to use what.

Comment: If you're using bash it is safer and better to use `[[ ... ]]`. `[` is archaic from bourne shell days and is actually an external executable.

Comment: Now try `./test1.sh "foo bar"`. `Testing -n (with quotes).` there are no quotes.

Comment: @KamilCuk `./test.sh: line 3: [: foo: binary operator expected`  So I should either use double square brackets or always use double quotes?

Comment: @anubhava Can you please expand on "external executable" in the context of variable that could contain sensitive data?

Comment: `[` is usually `/bin/[` on most of the systems. In Unix to pass variables on command line safely to an external binary, one needs to quote it. Hence quoting is must to have when using `[` but not when using `[[ ...]]` which is builtin

Comment: Thanks @anubhava... but is the content of variables leaked when using `[ `? Trying to figure out the security implications of using `[`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does not work as expected unless I use quotes... Why?

From [`man test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (and see also [posix test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)):

```
   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero

   STRING equivalent to -n STRING

   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

When `$1` is empty, then `[ -n $1 ]` executes `[ -n ]`. `[ STRING ]` is equivalent to `[ -n STRING ]`, so `[ -n ]` is equivalent to `[ -n -n ]`, and because `-n` is nonzero string, `[` succeeds.

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Unquoted variable expansion undergo [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) *and* filename expansion!

Research [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) and [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

---

> So I should ... always use double quotes?

As a rule of thumb you should always wrap expansions in double quotes.

> So I should ... use double square brackets ... ?

The `[[` is a bash extension not available in other shells, and from [[[ documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) we know that: `Word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]`, so that's why there is no need to (but it does no harm) to double quote expansions between `[[`. `[[` is specially handled by the shell, it's a special builtin with special syntax.

When working in bash-specific script that will never be ported, you may prefer `[[` over `[` because it should be tiny bit faster faster.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! According to some tests, `[[` appears to work in Z Shell as well... is that assumption correct?

Comment: Do you mean `[` is executed in a sub shell? Can you please expand in the context of variable that contains sensitive information? This answer is amazing!

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces, `test` and `[` are shell builtins.

Comment: `Z Shell as well... is that assumption correct?` Well, you tested it, why ask me? I would trust my computer more then some random guy on the net. See zsh documentation, I do not use zsh. `Do you mean [ is executed in a sub shell?` `[` is not a "shell", it''s a command. `Can you please expand in the context of variable that contains sensitive information?` No, because I do not understand how would "sensitive information" change anything.  `test and [ are shell builtins` Och, yes they are... I just remember that `[[` is tiny bit faster.