# Bash word splitting mechanism

Tags: string, bash, shell

I am new to Bash and I am seeing that there is automatic word splitting done by Bash:

```
a="1  2     3 4"
```

If I echo "a" by `echo $a` I got `1 2 3 4`, which has done word splitting implicitly. If I loop through "a", I got 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.

I also read from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) that

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.

And I also found that if I have

```
b=$a;
echo "$b"
```

I would get

```
"1 2 3 4"
```

So, here is my problem: when is the word splitting done? does it change the string itself? Does it only take effect when I use `echo` or `for` (loop)?

More generally, how does bash handle it?

Comment: Useful references: [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [Greg's Wiki - Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man bash`. For assignment, it says

> All values undergo tilde  expansion,  parameter and  variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal [ ... ] Word splitting is not performed, with the exception of "$@" as explained below under Special Parameters.  Pathname expansion is not performed.

Word splitting also does not happen in `[[ ]]` conditions:

> Word  splitting  and pathname  expansion  are  not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]

Comment: Great thanks! But does bash do word splitting on call instead of only once? I mean Bash always perform  splitting whenever it consider necessarily but not just do it the first time and then save it? If it does splitting for same string multiple times, I think the efficiency is not well considered?

Comment: If you need efficiency, don't use bash.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually several rounds of word-splitting. The first is performed prior to parsing the command line, so `echo $a` is split into two words `echo` and `$a`. (This is why something like `a="echo foo | wc -l"; $a` doesn't execute a pipeline; parsing is complete before `$a` is expanded). After that round of word-splitting is over, parameter expansion occurs to produce 2 strings, `echo` and `1 2 3 4`. The string resulting from parameter expansion then undergoes word-splitting itself, since it is not quoted, producing 4 additional words `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

In a for loop, the items in the list are subject to word-splitting:

```
for b in $a; do
```

is expanded (after word-splitting produces `for`, `b`, `in`, `$a`, `;`, and `do`) to `for`, `b`, `in`, `1 2 3 4`, `;`, and `do`. Again the string resulting from parameter expansion undergoes word-splitting to `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

Answer (score 4):

Bash works as next - when parsing a script or command line:

1. parsing and lexical analysis
2. expansion

   1. brace expansion
   2. tidle expansion
   3. variable expansion
   4. artithmetic and other substitutions
   5. command substitution
   6. **word splitting**
   7. filename generation (globbing)
3. removing quotes

as you can see, the word splitting is nearly at the end, so after the e.g. arithmetic exansion but before the filename globbing, Removing the quotes is the last step.

Comment: For readers less familiar with bash: although quote removal is the last step, it only removes quotes that _were already there before expansion_. If some metaprogramming is needed, we need to either say `sh -c "command with $variable"`, or `eval "command with $variable"`.