# How to get cygpath to take input from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cygwin, cygpath

I apologize in advance for this question, but I am really stuck right now, and I'm just praying that someone out there can help me.

I have a series of c files I need to inspect one at a time in about 100 subdirectories, each named balance.d, balanced.c, or balancer.c.  I've gotten a list of them using `find . -name "balance*"`, and I can choose one of those using `sed -n [NUM]p`.  This is a Windows environment using Cygwin, and these directories are all shared via Dropbox with other people.  The paths often involve spaces, and I am running into trouble.

I know that cygpath -sw will give me paths without spaces.  My eventual goal is to be able to grab each file, one at a time with `gcc path/to/file.c -o ./a.exe`

Right now, I've got

cygpath -sw $(echo find . -name "balance*" | sed -n 2p | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\ ")}8')

... but cygpath won't get my past the spaces.  It gives me an error

`` awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\ ' treated as plain ` ' ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around your command substitution or the result from it will undergo [work splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498218/bash-word-splitting-mechanism).

Also what you are doing with AWK part is not needed.

You are calling the `echo` command with the following arguments:

```
[find] [.] [-name] [balance*]
```

What you want it to call the find command:

```
cygpath -sw "$(find . -name "balance*" | sed -n 2p)"
```

Comment: It then gives me `cygpath: can't convert empty path` Could the doublequote characters inside the statement be causing trouble?

Comment: I don't use cygwin but I assume that's because you are taking a higher line number (`sed -n Xp`) than lines from the find command.

Comment: Try running `cygpath -sw ''` to confirm

Comment: When I run `echo find . -name "balance*" | sed -n 2p` I get `./DS 1. Smith, John Richard/lab 05/balance.c`  (I changed the name to protect the student)

Comment: Remove echo from the command: `find . -name "balance*" | sed -n 2p`