# How to pipe the value of date into sed?

Tags: bash, date, unix, sed

I want to have the value of

```
date + "%Y%m%d"
```

to be piped as the substituting word in sed

```
cat template.html | sed s/\\@\\@DATENUMBER\\@\\@/date +"%Y%m%d"/g
```

But this isn't allowed. How do I extract the value of the date and pipe it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed "s/@@DATENUMBER@@/$(date +"%Y%m%d")/g" template.html
```

Notes:

1. There is no need for `cat` because `sed` will take a file name as an argument.
2. If the text that you want to replace looks like `@@DATENUMBER@@`, then there is no need for all those backslashes: `@` is neither a shell-active character nor a sed-active character and does not need to be escaped.
3. If you want the `date` command to be executed, you have to use command substitution, `$(...)`.
4. The whole of the sed `s` command should be in quotes so that the shell does not do word splitting on it.

Comment: Thanks! What does "word splitting" mean in this context?

Comment: Your welcome.  For the original command, `sed` does not see a complete substitution command.  Instead it sees `s/\\@\\@DATENUMBER\\@\\@/date` as its first argument and  `+"%Y%m%d"/g` as its second argument.  Any time you have something that contains a space and you want the command to see it as a single argument, it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: For more on word splitting, see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18498494/3030305).  For an advanced discussion, see [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: Actually, in this particular case, word splitting will not result in multiple arguments - `sed s/@@DATENUMBER@@/$(date +%Y%m%d)/g template.html` is equivalent - though not recommended.  This works because the `date` command substitution will result in just digits, leaving no IFS in the argument.  I still recommend using the quotes, even if you're really sure what you're doing; the next person to read it might not be so sure, which is really annoying when that person is Future You...