# What does "plus colon" ("+:") mean in shell script expressions?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

What does this mean?

```
if ${ac_cv_lib_lept_pixCreate+:} false; then :
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  ac_check_lib_save_LIBS=$LIBS
```

Looks like `ac_cv_lib_lept_pixCreate` is some variable, so what does `+:` mean?

Where to learn complete syntax of curly bracket expressions? What is the name of this syntax?

Comment: That's a colon, not a comma.

Comment: : is a so-called POSIX special built-in

Comment: Read here for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin AND http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 31):

In the “plus colon” `${...+:}` expression, only the `+` has special meaning in the shell. The colon is just a string value in this case, so we could write that snippet as `${...+":"}`.  But, because it is also the first word in a shell command list, it becomes the *command* `:` which always returns *true*.

Depending on the question if the variable has a value or not, the `if` statement becomes either `if true false;`  or `if false;` .

---

Let's break it down:

For convenience, let's pretend the variable is called `var`, and consider the expression:

```
if ${var+:} false; then ...
```

If the shell variable `$var` exists, the entire expression is replaced with `:`, if not, it returns an empty string.

Therefore the entire expression `${var+:} false` becomes either `: false` (returning true) or `false` (returning false).

This comes down to a test for existence, which can be true even if the variable has no value assigned.

It is very cryptic, but as it happens, is one of the few tests for the existence of a variable that actually works in most, if not all, shells of Bourne descent.

Possible equivalents: (substitute any variable name here for `var`)

```
if [[ ${var+"is_set"} == is_set ]]; then ...
```

Or, probably more portable:

```
case ${var+"IS_SET"} in IS_SET) ...;; esac
```

Comment: In case you're wondering, autoconf does it this way because: not all shells support the `[[ ... ]]` syntax, the older `[ ... ]` aka `test ...` mechanism has a headache-inducing amount of variability across legacy Unixes and may not be built in (slowing things down), and finally, square brackets are a pain to use literally in autoconf code because they're repurposed for M4 quotation.

Comment: @Zack - good point - `autoconf` would need to take all possible shells in account.  I like my own bit of smart coding, but try to wrap special constructions in functions to isolate and explain their use -- which for this case would not work.

Comment: @Zack - updated the section about the cryptic idiom.

Comment: "*actually works in most, if not all, shells of Bourne descent.*". So, you're saying it works in shells born of Bourne?

Comment: Another variation: `[ "${var+fnord}" ]` will return true if `var` is set.

Comment: This is likely proof the creator of Bash was on LSD, and that LSD might not have beneficial effects on the human brain

Answer (score 20):

Shell Parameter Expansion documentation for bash is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). No mention of `+:`, though it does mention `:+`:

> `${parameter:+word}`
>   If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Comment: The leading colon is optional, so `${var+:}` means "substitute a colon here if `$var` is set to anything, otherwise substitute nothing.".

Comment: Not quite optional, but it can be omitted to provide a slightly different meaning. `${var:+:}` expands to `:` if `var` is unset or null. `${var+:}` expands to `:` only if `var` is unset, not if it has a null value.

Comment: The colon-less versions of the expansion operators are usually described collectively with `Omitting
       the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.` just before the list of operators is described.

Comment: @chepner I think you meant `${var:+:}` expands to `:` if var is NOT ( unset or null ); likewise, `${var+:}` expands to `:` if var is NOT unset.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Probably. The whole with/without colon thing makes more sense to me with the `${var:-}` operator, and I get confused when `${var:+}` is in some sense the inverse operator.

Answer (score 10):

To illustrate what has already been said:

Unset variable (note the blank lines as a result of some `echo` commands):

```
$ unset foo
$ echo ${foo}

$ echo ${foo:+:}

$ echo ${foo+:}
```

Null variable:

```
$ foo=""
$ echo ${foo}

$ echo ${foo:+:}

$ echo ${foo+:}
:
```

Non-null variable:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo ${foo}
bar
$ echo ${foo:+:}
:
$ echo ${foo+:}
:
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple examples will prove

I check for presence of a parameter TEST, if present echo "Yes" else I echo "No"

```
openvas:~$ ${TEST+:} false  &&  echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
openvas:~$ TEST=1
openvas:~$ ${TEST+:} false  &&  echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
openvas:~$
```

If you see, the parameter TEST is evaluated and it is actually unset, so it returns false and exit the path and goes to the OR
Once I set the same, and test again, it flows to the echo part (continued &&) since it returns true

Refer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) and [that](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: Technically, the first `TEST` is unset, not null.

Comment: Not a suitable exemple. `${TEST} false  &&  echo "yes" || echo "no"` also prints no. So that doesn't pinpoint what +: adds to the mix.