# How to check if an environment variable exists and get its value?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script. In this shell script, I am have a variable that either takes a default value, or the value of an environment variable. However, the environment variable doesn't have to be present.

For instance, assume, before running the script, I perform the following operation:

```
export DEPLOY_ENV=dev
```

How do I tell the script to search for this environment variable, and store its value in a variable inside the script. Moreover, how do I tell the script that if this environment variable does not exist, store a default variable?

Comment: `printenv DEPLOY_ENV` should do it

Comment: I tried, for testing purposes
    tempV=$(printenv LANG) it did not print anything, despite the system having the value of LANG

Comment: Your statement doesn't "print" anything. It stores the value of the environment variable `LANG` into the shell variable `tempV`.  As for the other suggestions in this thread: Note that with none of them, you can distinguish, whether you have an environment variable or a shell variable. If this distinction is really important, the solution suggested by @sjsam should be considered.

Answer (score 843, accepted):

`[ -z "${DEPLOY_ENV}" ]` checks whether `DEPLOY_ENV` has length equal to zero. So you could run:

```
if [[ -z "${DEPLOY_ENV}" ]]; then
  MY_SCRIPT_VARIABLE="Some default value because DEPLOY_ENV is undefined"
else
  MY_SCRIPT_VARIABLE="${DEPLOY_ENV}"
fi

# or using a short-hand version

[[ -z "${DEPLOY_ENV}" ]] && MyVar='default' || MyVar="${DEPLOY_ENV}"

# or even shorter use

MyVar="${DEPLOY_ENV:-default_value}"
```

Comment: You can replace `"${DEPLOY_ENV}"` with `$DEPLOY_ENV`

Comment: `MyVar="$DEPLOY_ENV:-default_value"` didn't work for me though on bash, so it's generally safer to surround with curly braces `${...}` where possible.

Comment: the 'or even shorter use' made my day!

Comment: The remove curly brackets thing was not for the this proposal but only for when you use the variable directly without the additional expansion

Comment: This works and may have value in edge cases, but it's a re-invented wheel... Instead, see the parameter "expansion answer", which was made for this exact goal.

Comment: @Finesse `Always quote a tested string.`
https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: This will error if you use `set -euo pipefail`. You need to use @Eugene method of default values first before the `-z` test `MyVar=${DEPLOY_ENV:-}`

Comment: The reason I don't like this solution is that it does check if variable exist or not but I dont want it to check if variable is empty as well. For example, if variable abc="" , the -z test will say abc is empty but I don't care that.

Comment: There is even a better syntax :  `MyVar = ${DEPLOY_ENV:-default}`

Comment: If an env var has a valid empty string value, this is answer not quite correct as the value is set, but has a zero-length value.  These are not the same.  See Eugene's answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "unbound variable" when the var is not set.

Answer (score 196):

You could just use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> *${parameter:-word}*
>
> If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

So try this:

```
var=${DEPLOY_ENV:-default_value}
```

There's also the *${parameter-word}* form, which substitutes the default value only when *parameter* is unset (but not when it's null).

To demonstrate the difference between the two:

```
$ unset DEPLOY_ENV
$ echo "'${DEPLOY_ENV:-default_value}' '${DEPLOY_ENV-default_value}'"
'default_value' 'default_value'
$ DEPLOY_ENV=
$ echo "'${DEPLOY_ENV:-default_value}' '${DEPLOY_ENV-default_value}'"
'default_value' ''
```

Comment: My script was not able to read the value of DEPLOY_ENV, In order to be sure that the environment variable exists in the system, I wrote printenv DEPLOY_ENV in the terminal, and the correct value was returned. However, the script was not able to fetch it.

Answer (score 123):

If you don't care about the difference between an unset variable or a variable with an empty value, you can use the default-value parameter expansion:

```
foo=${DEPLOY_ENV:-default}
```

If you *do* care about the difference, drop the colon

```
foo=${DEPLOY_ENV-default}
```

You can also use the `-v` operator to explicitly test if a parameter is set.

```
if [[ ! -v DEPLOY_ENV ]]; then
    echo "DEPLOY_ENV is not set"
elif [[ -z "$DEPLOY_ENV" ]]; then
    echo "DEPLOY_ENV is set to the empty string"
else
    echo "DEPLOY_ENV has the value: $DEPLOY_ENV"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the `-v` option was introduced in Bash 4.2, and many systems are still running older versions of Bash.

Comment: Even `bash` 4.2 is over 5 years old at this point; I tend to treat anything older as a special case that deserves special mention in the question.

Comment: It is amazing how time flies...

Comment: This code gives me `./deploy.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected` - at least on mac for `if [[ ! -v DEPLOY_ENV ]]; then`

Comment: @anon58192932 That's because you are using `/bin/bash`, which is only version 3.2.x on Mac OS X.

Comment: the list of reasons to switch to linux gets another entry... thanks @chepner

Comment: You can install a new version yourself.

Comment: beware that "-v" might fail test for hashes and arrays. It returns false unless the variable has an element of key/indice "0". Also it doesn't work for special parameters like $1, $-, $#...  Use declare -p / typeset -p  instead!

Comment: @DmitryShevkoplyas `-v` has worked for arrays (both indexed and associative) since `bash` 4.2. The special parameters are either always set, or indeed handled differently. (For example, test the value of `$#` to see which positional parameters are actually set.)

Comment: macos even in 2020 (Catalina) uses GPLv2 bash3.x, you need to account for that or the user needs to `brew install bash`, and your scripts should use `/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Don't use `/usr/bin/env bash`, unless you are the only one using the script. The version of `bash` your script requires may  not be the same version that `env` will run for someone else.

Comment: In POSIX `[[` is undefined but the fix is easy, just use a single bracket `[` instead.

Comment: @GunarGessner POSIX `[` doesn't have a `-v` operator, so in this context just using `[` isn't a solution.

Answer (score 63):

There is no difference between environment variables and variables in a script. Environment variables are just defined earlier, outside the script, before the script is called. From the script's point of view, a variable is a variable.

You can check if a variable is defined:

```
if [ -z "$a" ]
then
    echo "not defined"
else 
    echo "defined"
fi
```

and then set a default value for undefined variables or do something else.

The `-z` checks for a zero-length (i.e. empty) string. See `man bash` and look for the CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section.

You can also use `set -u` at the beginning of your script to make it fail once it encounters an undefined variable, if you want to avoid having an undefined variable breaking things in creative ways.

Comment: "There is no difference between environment variables and variables in a script." -- to clarify: this is not true in the important sense that, while an environment variable is also a shell variable, a shell variable is not always exported as an environment variable.  Here are some ways to tell if a variable is exported: https://superuser.com/questions/450868/what-is-the-simplest-scriptable-way-to-check-whether-a-shell-variable-is-exporte

Comment: Not true. If you set env variable to an empty string this still returns "not defined".

Answer (score 7):

```
NEW_VAR=""
if [[ ${ENV_VAR} && ${ENV_VAR-x} ]]; then
  NEW_VAR=${ENV_VAR}
else
  NEW_VAR="new value"
fi
```