# Linux Check if PATH exists

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a shell script that checks if an environment variable has been added, otherwise.

```sh
if [ ! echo $PATH | grep "/what_i_want_to_add" ]; then # If there is no environment variable
    export PATH=$PATH:/what_i_want_to_add
fi
```

If possible, I would like to discard the output using /dev/null.
what should i do?

Comment: AMATEUR_TOSS Check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296472/how-to-check-if-an-environment-variable-exists-and-get-its-value

Comment: `what should i do?` Read about test command in shell programming language. Read about `if` statement in shell programming language. Read about `grep` and how to use it and learn about `-q` option. Research word splitting, and why quoting of variables is needed. Use shellcheck.net to check comon mistakes

Comment: @AMATEUR_TOSS : Please ask in an understandable way: The question title is about an environment variable to **exist**, and the question text is about an environment variable to be **added**. Also, you ask about how to discard output. This is a separate question; please don't ask two unrelated things in one question. Lastly the code you posted, has nothing to do with the **existence** of environment variables, but about their **contents**.

Comment: Note the `-q` option to grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function used on archlinux inside `/etc/profile`. It works flawlessly when adding path to `PATH`.

```
# Append our default paths
appendpath () {
    case ":$PATH:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}$1"
    esac
}

# usage example:
appendpath '/what_i_want_to_add'
```

- `case ":$PATH:" in` - match `$PATH` but with a trailing and leading colon, so that we can:

  - `*:"$1":*)` - match `:$PATH:` with anything, followed by a colon, followed by the argument, followed by colon, and anything. Because we used `":$PATH:"` it will expand to `:/path1:/path/2:/path/3:` that can be matched against `*:/path1:*` with globbing expression.

    - If the match is successful, do nothing
  - `*)` - else

    - Add the argument to `PATH`.
    - `${PATH:+$PATH:}` - A shell parameter expansion. If `PATH` is empty or NULL, then expand to nothing. If the path is not empty, then expand to `$PATH` followed by a colon. This can handle an empty `PATH=` argument so that leading empty `:` is not added.