# How to check dynamically that a Bash variable exists?

Tags: bash, variables

Please consider the following Bash function.

```
#!/bin/bash

function assert_var(){
  echo "check if variable with name $1 exists"
  if [ -z $1 ];then
    echo "EXISTS!"
  else
    echo "NOT EXISTS!"
  fi
}


export FOO="123"
assert_var "FOO"
assert_var "BAR"
```

The expectation is that variable FOO should be detected and absence of BAR as well.
For that, I need somehow to pass and use the variable name as argument to the function.

How to do that properly?

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221093/bash-function-to-check-if-a-given-variable-is-set/44221215

Comment: Be sure to use `-v`, though. The more upvoted duplicate is old and has more upvotes for answers that predate `-v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do the job for you:

```
assert_var() {
   if [[ -z ${!1+x} ]]; then
      echo 'NOT EXISTS!'
   else
      echo 'EXISTS!'
   fi
}
```

**Changes are:**

- Use `${var+x}` to check if a variable is unset. `${var+x}` is a parameter expansion that evaluates to nothing if `var` is unset, and substitutes the string `x` otherwise. [More details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)
- Use indirect referencing of variable by name i.e. `${!1+x}` instead of `${1+x}`
- Use single quotes when you are using `!` in string to avoid history expansion

**Testing:**

```
FOO='123'
assert_var "FOO"
EXISTS!
assert_var "BAR"
NOT EXISTS!
```

Comment: Can you explain what `${!1+x}` is doing?

Comment: yes I just added