# Difference between [[ -n $VAR ]] and [[ $VAR ]] in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a difference between these two options in Bash:

```
# 1
if [[ "$VAR" ]]; then 

#2
if [[ -n "$VAR" ]]; then
```

If not, are there situations that really require the `-n` option?

Comment: By the way, you don't need quotes around `$VAR` here.  You do need quotes if you used `test` `[`, or for literals containing whitespace.  The quotes are not doing any harm though.

Comment: I'm not sure I will ever truly understand quotes and whitespace handling in Bash. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for non-zero length string in Bash: \[ -n "$var" \] or \[ "$var" \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869072/test-for-non-zero-length-string-in-bash-n-var-or-var)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `[[` is smarter than `test` about variables there are essentially no situations that require `-n`.

```
$ foo=-n
$ [[ $foo ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -n ]] ; echo $?
bash: unexpected argument `]]' to conditional unary operator
bash: syntax error near `]]'
$ foo="-z bar"
$ [[ $foo ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [ $foo ] ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Wow, what a great edge case test.