# Improve script output

Tags: bash

I have written a function which checks whether one or more variables passed as arguments are empty ([got the idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function))

Here is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
is_variable_defined?() {
 for VAR in "$@"; do
  : "${!VAR? "ERROR: $VAR is undefined."}"
 done
}

TEST='a'

is_variable_defined? TEST TEST2
```

And here is the output:

```
/path/to/script.sh: line 4: !VAR:  ERROR: TEST2 is undefined.
```

However what I would like to output is:

```
TEST2 is undefined
```

I have tried tweaking the `: "${!VAR? "ERROR: $VAR is undefined."}"` line but whatever I do it breaks.

Does anybody know what to modify in the script to get the output I want?

Comment: Did you even read the answer from the question you link to? It's **intended** to break with that message. The answer on the other question holds the answer, as far as I can see it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash. Test for a variable unset, using a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function)

Comment: hence my question, how can I change the message?

Comment: You can't, it's a built in function. May I quote from [lhunath answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function/874520#874520) from that other question: `If you just want to test whether foo is empty, instead of aborting the script, use this instead of a function: [[ $foo ]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing if the variable is undefined or simply a null string?

### Null Test

```
is_variable_defined() {
    for var in $@
    do
        if [ -z ${!var} ]   # Or if [[ ${!var} ]]
        then
            echo "Var $var has no value"
        fi
    done
}
```

### Undefined Test

```
is_variable_defined() {
for var in $@
do
     if ! set | grep -q "^$var="
     then
        echo "Var $var is not set"
     fi
done
```

The last is looking at the output of the `set` command to see if the variable is listed there. The `-q` will make `grep` *quiet*. And you look at the exit status to see if it found the string. If your `grep` doesn't support the `-q` parameter, you can try `grep "^$var=" 2> /dev/null`.

---

Using the `[[ $foo ]]` syntax for testing won't necessarily work. The below will print *`$foo is not set`* even though it was set to an empty string:

```
foo=""
if [[ $foo ]]
then
      echo "\$foo = '$foo'"
else
      echo "\$foo is not set"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for introducing the `set` command, although relying on grep to verify a variable status may not be as robust as the `[[ $foo ]]` function suggested by Bobby.

Comment: The problem is that `[[ $foo ]]` also will fail if `$foo` has a value, but is null. The `set` test can tell the difference between `foo` having a value that's null and `$foo` not being set.