# Why is my bash function returning an unexpected return code?

Tags: bash, function, return-code

I have been creating a small library of bash functions to encapsulate some of the more arcane bash syntax structures into routines that I can quickly use and reference.  But for some of them, I'm running into unexpected return codes from my functions.  The 'is_undefined' function below is one such example.  Can anyone explain the results I am getting?  (Also provided below.)

```
#!/bin/bash

is_undefined ()
{
  # aka "unset" (not to be confused with "set to nothing")
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function
  [ -z ${1+x} ]
}

if [ -z ${UNDEFINED+x} ]; then
  echo "inline method reports that \$UNDEFINED is undefined"
fi

if is_undefined UNDEFINED; then
  echo "is_undefined() reports that \$UNDEFINED is undefined"
else
  echo "is_undefined() reports that \$UNDEFINED is defined"
fi

DEFINED=
if is_undefined DEFINED; then
  echo "is_undefined() reports that \$DEFINED is undefined"
else
  echo "is_undefined() reports that \$DEFINED is defined"
fi
```

The surprising results are:

```
$ ./test.sh
inline method reports that $UNDEFINED is undefined
is_undefined() reports that $UNDEFINED is defined
is_undefined() reports that $DEFINED is defined
```

Comment: add `set -vx` to see how/what is being processed when. Good luck.

Comment: The newest version of `bash` has a `-v` operator to test if a variable is set. `[[ -v foo ]]` succeeds only if `foo` is not set; if `foo` is set to the empty string it fails.

Comment: Regarding -v: I managed to get that into my code several months back, but forgot to document a reference.  I removed it last night because I failed to find it mentioned in my bash book, and googling it yielded no results.  I thought I must have imagined it...  I guess not! :)

Comment: Oh, and my description of `-v`is completely backwards :( `-v foo` is true when `foo` *is* set, and false otherwise. Introduced in 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside `is_undefined` you are testing `$1`, not `${UNDEFINED}`, to do that you need throw in variable indirection like

```
is_undefined () {
    [ -z "${!1+x}" ]
}
```

However, that is bashism and not posix compliant. For posix compliacy you will need

```
is_undefined () {
    eval "[ -z \${$1+x} ]"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`is_undefined UDEFINED` returns true, because the test inside `is_undefined` doesn't test `UNDEFINED` but `$1`, and `$1` *is* defined. It's value is `UNDEFINED`.

So, your function should always return true, as long as you provide a parameter. The only time it will return false, should be when you call it with no arguments

```
is_undefined
```

To get `is_undefined` test the actual variable, you can use variable indirection with an exclamation mark `!`, see [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
is_undefined ()
{
  # aka "unset" (not to be confused with "set to nothing")
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function
  [ -z "${!1+x}" ]
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  But what must I do to dereference $1 within that expression inside `is_undefined()`, to get the behavior I desire?

Comment: You can use variable indirection, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  (Meta: I am uncertain whether to accept your answer, or @yaccz's answer.  He provided the variable indirection component slightly before you did, but both of your answers were equally helpful.  What's etiquette, in this scenario?)

Comment: I don't know about any etiquette, in the end it's up to you. In either case, I won't mind, if you accept his answer.